# Which predictions of the Force Awakens: Darths & Droids Bingo were correct?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

The team of the Darths & Droids screencap webcomic have produced [The Force Awakens Bingo](http://www.darthsanddroids.net/bingo/Episode7/), which contains predictions about *Star Wars: The Force Awakens*.

> Are you seeing *The Force Awakens* soon? Get at least twice the fun by printing out one of our [Force Awakens bingo cards](http://www.darthsanddroids.net/bingo/Episode7/) and playing in the cinema! (No spoilers - we're just guessing what may or may not happen in the movie. We don't know any more than you!)

**Which of [the predictions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yX7DS.jpg) were correct for the film?**

**Update**: For most of the questions, a one-line answer suffices.  For events that clearly didn't appear on screen, like building a new lightsaber, just a "no" suffices.  For events that did occur, like the Wilhelm's Scream, please mention the scene where it occurs.  Only a very few predictions (near misses or ambiguous occurances) merit explanations, but it may be better to link to a separate question in that case (eg. [on whether the antagonists in this film are Sith](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/110922/4918)).

**Update:**  The two answers disagree on predictions on 21, 30, 33.

1. Someone gets a hand cut off
2. Someone has a bad feeling about “this”
3. BB-8’s head comes off
4. C-3PO says how many forms of communication he’s fluent in
5. Wilhelm scream
6. An alien talks with subtitles
7. “May the Force be with you.”
8. Something is a trap!
9. Percussive maintenance on the Millennium Falcon
10. Chewie welds something
11. R2-D2 plugs into a computer terminal socket
12. Han shoots someone first
13. Someone we thought was dead turns out to be alive
14. A Force ghost appears
15. Someone constructs a new lightsaber
16. Jar Jar Binks
17. A new single biome planet
18. Hyperdrive malfunction
19. A yellow lightsaber
20. An alien animal attacks!
21. An asteroid field!
22. Lightsaber wield combo more epic than ever seen before
23. New fighter named after a letter of the alphabet
24. Summon bigger fish!
25. Someone serving bizarre alien drinks
26. Alien band plays music
27. Vehicle hovers when it would work just as well or better with wheels
28. Bottomless pit without a railing
29. Transparent computer display
30. Sign or display in Aurebesh script
31. A new Force ability
32. Big “Noooooo!!”
33. Someone gets Force choked
34. Alien speaks English in an ethnic accent
35. Alien speaks alien language and Han replies in English
36. Someone mentions midi-chlorians
37. Lens flare
38. Clock wipe between scenes
39. Line that gets more amusing if you replace “Force” with “pants”
40. Lightsaber used for a non-combat purpose
41. R2-D2 falls over
42. C-3PO is damaged
43. On-screen kiss
44. Someone says “I love you.”
45. John Williams score reprises a theme from original trilogy (credits don’t count)
46. R2-D2 uses a tool we’ve never seen before
47. Scene involving food
48. Vehicle with legs
49. Giant monster based on real world insect or other small animal
50. Creature that lives in vacuum of space
51. Jedi mind trick
52. Line repeats never before repeated line from original trilogy
53. An escape pod ejects from a ship
54. Blaster shot ricochets and kills someone
55. Bigger than life size hologram
56. Someone is immune to Jedi mind tricks
57. Real world unit of measurement (e.g. metres, parsecs)
58. Running duel moves from one location to another
59. Someone foresees the future
60. Someone swings on a rope or vine
61. Character who died in first six movies mentioned by name
62. C-3PO says something about space travel
63. Death of an original trilogy character
64. Obvious video game level scene
65. New alien species obviously designed to appeal to kids
66. Someone is identified as a clone
67. A bad guy successfully shoots someone
68. Mooks firing en masse and repeatedly missing
69. Droids walk through a crossfire without getting hit
70. Sith apprentice kills master
71. Sith master arranges death of apprentice
72. A droid fixes a spaceship
73. R2-D2 sits in an astromech port in a spaceship
74. Darth X, where X prefixed with “in” is a word

Notes.

- The above is my transcript [of the cards](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yX7DS.jpg).  The question is about the original cards, so whenever my transcript is incorrect, edit the above and answer about the originals.
- Some of the predictions may be funnier if you are familiar with the webcomic, but it should be possible to understand every prediction without that.
- Some of the predictions use TvTropes lingo, but only the more transparent of it.
- [The Darths & Droids forum thread "SPOILER THREAD for The Force Awakens"](http://www.irregularwebcomic.net/draakslair/viewtopic.php?p=154660#154660) mentions the bingo a little, eg. [aurilee mentions the surprising lack of percussive maintenance on the Millenium Falcon](http://www.irregularwebcomic.net/draakslair/viewtopic.php?p=154674#154674).

Comment: For close voters: Note that *finite, definitively answerable* list questions are considered on-topic on this site.

Comment: For close voters.  This question already has two answers, and any new information can be edited into them.  Strike the question down and it will become more powerful than you'd ever realize.

Comment: Is 74 questions in one post a record?

Comment: re: your chat message: You're welcome. I'm not finished with the answer, BTW. I typically comment to the OP if I majorly update an old answer, I didn't ping you simply because in my mind I haven't done updates that are worth pinging about, yet :)   Also, you can use RSS feed but I'm unsure if SE has RSS feesds for specific questions (as opposed to whole site or individual tags)

Comment: @user14111 - I think so. I was tempted to suggest to split it up into 74 individual questions, but then someone would post that i'm a rep-grabbing jerk, so i figured I'm not gonna subject myself to that just to make sure a question follows the site's literal rules.

Comment: @MikeEdenfield - the problem with this question (insofar as it has a problem, which is debatable in the first place :) isn't that it is a "list" question but that it contains several independent questions - typically, we close  as "too broad" or at least drastically edit a question when it contains **two** independent questions.

Comment: The largest I know is http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/107467/4918 "What are the names of all the sci-fi vessels in this artwork?" which has 64 objects to be identified.

Comment: @user14111: it's no longer a record: today's question http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/139583/4918 "Who are the characters on this Legend of Zelda poster?" apparently has 97 characters to identify.

Comment: And now even that has been surpassed: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/171218/4918 "Can we identify all the characters in this Universe 113 poster?" has an even higher number of elements to identify.

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/119845/4918 "Who are these people at Deadpool's wedding?" has 236 characters, thus exceeding even the Universe 113 one which has about 200 objects.

Comment: The new record is https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/218073/4918 Who are the 378 mutants in this image? (Marvel) with over 390 characters.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

**UPDATE: several major updates including NOs becoming "part yes" or "maybe" as of 2015/01/19**

*All quotes below, unless otherwise noted, are from WGA script. Some may be from Alan Dean Foster's novelization of TFA, the style is absolutely different so they are easy to tell apart. Anything with tons of CAPITALIZATION is a script :)*.

1. Someone gets a hand cut off

   No. Yes if you widen the interpretation a LOT.

   - There are suspicions that Finn's was. Neither the film nor novelizations are quite clear on what his injuries were, other than they were inflicted by a lightsaber and life-threatening. We'll know in Episode VIII.
   - It was conclusively shown that [Kylo Ren's was NOT](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/111947/did-this-character-lose-a-limb-in-the-force-awakens?lq=1).
   - C-3PO [had an arm replaced](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/110838/why-does-this-character-have-a-red-arm) before the events of the film. [He replaced it back with gold arm by the film's end](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/113950/976).
   - HOWEVER, Chewie literally **rips someone's arm off** in the Foster novelization:

     > **Grabbing the thrusting arm, a roaring Chewbacca twisted and ripped it off at the shoulder, throwing the dismembered limb clear across the room**. Looking down at himself, Plutt let out a scream of agony as his underlings hurriedly fell back.

     Please note that this scene is *unique to the novelization and NOT in the theater film release* (perhaps a deleted scene?). But the novelization is fully Disney canon.
2. Someone has a bad feeling about "this"

   Yes. Han, of course.

   > That was when the lights began to flicker. Laughter faded as Kanji and Guavian alike regarded the now sporadic illumination with uncertainty. Distant components cycling on and off filled the corridor with a clicking and gnashing like the cries of a thousand mechanical insects. **Han**’s eyes widened. With Chewie moaning beside him, he murmured softly.
   >   **"I got a bad feeling about this."**

   From the WGA script (right after Rathtars are released):

   > Han's eyes go wide -- he gets it -- and it's bad. QUIETLY:
   >   HAN
   >   ... I got a bad feeling about this...
3. BB-8’s head comes off

   No.

   But [we know creative team actually thought what would happen to his head of power cut off](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/112205/976).
4. C-3PO says how many forms of communication he’s fluent in

   **No**. Checked the book text and the script for "communication", "million" and "language" too.

   HOWEVER, he actually, unlike the prior films, *"shows, not tells"*, his skills!

   In the novelization, wholly fulfilling his ANH-stated function of "human-cyborg relations", he figures out how to query all the Droids in the Galaxy (it seems) **and finds BB-8** for Leia at Maz's castle, thus making sure Resistance arrives to save the heroes there on time.
5. Wilhelm scream

   [**Yes**](http://dorksideoftheforce.com/2015/12/24/was-the-wilhelm-scream-in-star-wars-the-force-awakens/).

   In the hangar of the Star Destroyer when Finn and Poe are escaping.
6. An alien talks with subtitles

   **Kinda, Maybe. From a certain point of view**. Depends on how you define "alien", "subtitles" and "is" :)

   1. GA-97 (droid who reported to Resistance from Maz's cantina that the heroes were on Takodana) speaks in Binary and has subtitles.

      > A SMALL DROID (GA-97), who turns its head to see BB-8 following Rey across the room. GA-97, now animated, makes a **small TRANSMITTING SOUND, which is subtitled**.
      >   GA-97
      >   Alert the Resistance. Their missing droid is here!
   2. The gangster Tasu Leech! (talking to Han, naturally).

      However, he is human; not alien, strictly speaking.

      > "Tasu Leech! Good to see you!"
      >   Han knew perfectly well that **Tasu Leech would never deign to speak Basic**, so he was not surprised when **the man replied in another language—one with which Han was, fortunately, familiar**.
      >   "Wrong again, Solo. It’s over for you, and for your associate." Raising the weapon he held, Leech aimed it down the corridor.
   3. Also, Maz speaks in some alien language, but instead of subtitles, she translates herself.
   4. Also, we get subtitles when Bazine reports her spy report to First Order from Maz's. But as per Visual Dictionary, she's human as well.

      > Bazine enters a shadowy space, stealthily makes a call on a communicator. Clearly, **BAZINE IS A SPY. Subtitled**:
      >   BAZINE
      >   Inform the First Order... I've found the droid.
7. "May the Force be with you."

   **Yes**.

   Leia to Rey at the end.

   > LEIA
   >   Rey.
   >   Rey turns around.
   >   LEIA (CONT'D)
   >   May the Force be with you.
   >   This fills Rey up. She smiles gratefully. Rey crosses to the Falcon.
   >   (*WGA Script*)

   and

   > Rey replied in all seriousness. "But you’re also afraid. In sending me away, you’re—reminded."
   >   Leia straightened. "You won’t share the fate of our son."
   >   "I know what we’re doing is right. This is how it has to be. This is how it should be."
   >   Leia smiled gently, reassuringly. "I know it, too. **May the Force be with you**."
   >   (*Foster Novelization*)
8. Something is a trap!

   **No**. Double checked by searching novelization text AND leaked WGA script.

   However, Finn and Rey discuss trapping the gangsters.

   > REY
   >   Wait wait wait wait. If we close the blast doors in that corridor, we **can trap both gangs**!
9. Percussive maintenance on the Millennium Falcon

   No.

   Confirmed in the script and novelization as well.

   Han kinda moves at one point like he wants to but Rey pre-empts it.

   Gentle female touch means you (Rey) just know which buttons to press. Novelization keeps emphasizing that.
10. Chewie welds something

    No.

    He's shot and injured before getting from Eravana to Falcon.

    He does stay behind at Maz's castle, to check Falcon but no welding is mentioned in film or script or novelization.

    And he checks the Falcon before flying to Starkiller. A

    And later before flying to Ah-Choo! - no welding either way.
11. R2-D2 plugs into a computer terminal socket

    Conceptually, yes. 30 years ago, into Death Star, where he got Luke's map half.

    In film, **NO**.
12. Han shoots someone first

    Yes, but they had it coming (stormtroopers).

    As a trope from ANH, **no**.
13. Someone we thought was dead turns out to be alive

    - Finn AND Resistance both **thought that Poe died** in TIE/se crash.

      > "They found his X-wing destroyed. Angle and depth of the blaster marks suggest it was blown up while still on the ground. Definitely First Order: The locals don’t have access to that kind of weaponry." His expression tightened. "**There’s no indication he survived. It looks like we’ve lost him.**"

      and

      > Finn studied him intently. "You look like you’re in one piece. I can hardly believe it. **I thought you were dead: shot up in that TIE fighter we stole**. I ejected. When I finally found the wreckage, I looked for you. Pulled your jacket out of your ship before it got swallowed by the sand. What happened to you?"
    - Not sure if it fits or not, but Finn was thought of as dead, or at least not sure to survive, even in-universe, till the Doctor assure Rey he would.

      > FINN, who lies, **near death**, not far from where the GROUND FELL AWAY. Rey falls to her knees near him, turns him over, sees his **cauterized but possibly fatal wound**.
      >   REY
      >   Finn! Finn...
      >   Tears come to her eyes as she lifts him, holds his **lifeless body** in her arms. Snow flurries around them as she cries, holding this boy who she just met, who she already adores.
14. A Force ghost appears

    Not visually. **Yes in sounds**.

    We get voices from Obi-Wan (new and old) and Yoda, [in Rey's flashback](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/111978/976). Not sure if that counts.

    It was confirmed from WoG that Snoke is NOT a force ghost.
15. Someone constructs a new lightsaber

    Yes. [Kylo Ren's Christmas Tree lightsaber](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/111559/976). But that doesn't happen on-screen, of course (neither did any prior films).
16. Jar Jar Binks

    **No**! [J.J. Abrams planned to kill him off, as an Easter Egg, however](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/112214/976).
17. A new single biome planet

    4 of them (2 for sure).

    - **Desert** (Jakku)

      > It was a peaceful place, as was the case with most small communities situated on **desert worlds**
    - Forest? Green world (Takodana). I would say it may count but probably not.

      > THERE MAY HAVE been more beautiful worlds in the galaxy than Takodana, but if so, they were unknown to Han. Verdant and mild, flecked with bands of white cloud and necklaced with small seas and brightly reflective lakes...
      >   "I didn’t know there was this much green in the whole galaxy," she said in awe.
    - **Arctic/Ice** (Starkiller)

      > The fleet of Star Destroyers stood off the **white world**. Spectacular and isolated, **with a mean surface temperature varying from merely cold to permanently arctic**...
    - Waterworld (<strike>Kevin Costner's</strike> Luke's planet)

      > The planet was **mostly ocean**, dotted with a sprinkling of towering islands formed of black rock: the throats of volcanoes whose slopes had long since eroded away. Greenery caped the stony flanks, falling in emerald waves toward the azure sea. Above the calm waters, flying creatures soared on wide wings of translucent white.
18. Hyperdrive malfunction

    Yes. Kinda. But because Han forgot to turn something on.

    > "Come on, baby," Han was murmuring, "don’t let me down." He pulled on the main hyperdrive control.
    >   Nothing.
    >   "What?"
    >   Reaching across to his side of the console, Rey calmly activated a control he had not touched and spoke matter-of-factly. "Compressor."
19. A yellow lightsaber

    No (but partially yes).

    The only 2 lightsabers we see are Kylo Ren's red, and Luke's old blue.

    However, the WGA script calls Kylo Ren's lightsaber "yellow/red"!

    > Suddenly Kylo Ren raises his LIGHTSABER -- IGNITES IT --
    >   PERPENDICULAR SMALLER BLADES AT THE HILT, A UNIQUE BUZZ --
    >   **YELLOW/RED ENERGY**, SPITTING SPARKS AND SMOKE --

    Also, Harrison Ford told Conan O'Brien in an interview he'd like a *pink* one.
20. An alien animal attacks!

    Yes. [Rathtars](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/111269/976).
21. An asteroid field!

    Yes. Falcon flies by the asteroid field near D'Qar *right before* before jumping to lightspeed to go find Luke. We also see the exact same asteroid field earlier, when Falcon flies to D'Qar with Han and Finn.

    [image: asteroids!]

    > EXT. SPACE - DAY
    >   The FALCON and surviving X-WINGS ROAR past camera toward a PLANET WITH GREEN FLORA **AND A RING OF ASTEROIDS**
22. Lightsaber wield combo more epic than ever seen before

    No. Nothing and nobody will ever top Yoda in Episode II, or Dooku's skill.

    Remember, in this film the only lightsaber fights are:

    - Kylo Ren killing a *captive* Muggle on Jakku.
    - Kylo Ren killing a bunch of furniture on Star Destroyer.
    - Rey's Forceback, where she sees Kylo Ren spearing someone with LS.
    - Finn (who never held a LS before) fighting a Stormtrooper.
    - Kylo Ren killing unresisting Han Solo (d&^k move!)
    - Kylo Ren fighting Finn. Finn has no idea what he's doing (mostly), Ren is [&^*ing around](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/112257/976) and [isn't up to full speed](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/112013/976)
    - Kylo Ren fighting Rey. Again, he's under the weather, so to speak, and she never held a LS before.
23. New fighter named after a letter of the alphabet

    Not a fighter. We get only 3 fighters, T-70 X-Wings, and TIE/fo and TIE/sf.

    BUT, we do get a brand new [Upsilon-class](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Upsilon-class_command_shuttle) assault shuttle. It isn't a fighter; and as other shuttles in old films, named after Greek alphabet, not Latin.
24. Summon bigger fish!

    Strictly speaking, no. The only dangerous animals are Rathtars.

    Conceptually, yes (if smaller fish is the gangsters from Death Gang or Kanjiklub and bigger fish are Rathtars).
25. Someone serving bizarre alien drinks

    Yes. Maz Kanata's castle. Han even calls it a "watering hole"

    > "The galaxy’s full of **watering holes**, but nothing like this place. It’s been run by an old smuggler named Maz Kanata for a thousand years...
    >
    > The entrance was open. A corridor led to a sizable open hall of neatly finished stonework where a hodgepodge of humans, humanoids, and distinctly nonhumans were engaged in what struck Finn as a perpetual round of **eating**, **drinking**, gambling, scheming....
26. Alien band plays music

    Yes. Maz Kanata's castle has a very Mos-Eisley-ish alien band.

    Visual Dictionary (page 73) covers it in details ([as does this SE answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/113861/976)), its members are Taybin Ralorsa, Infrablue Zedbeddy Coggins, Ubert "Sticks" Quaril and Sudswater Dillifay Glon. No, I didn't make the names up - see the linked answer for screenshot.

    According to Pablo Hidalgo's twitter, the names are meant to be "blues" invoking.
27. Vehicle hovers when it would work just as well or better with wheels

    Too subjective to call.

    Maybe, Ray's podracer-like speeder. I don't think so but some people do.
28. Bottomless pit without a railing

    Yes. Han falls into one after being lightsabered by Kylo Ren (spoilers!)

    > Finally Han FALLS BACK, OFF THE CATWALK, **INTO THE DEPTHS OF THE STRUCTURE**!

    Also, later, a bottomless planetary crack separates Rey and Ren

    > But she stops. Realizing she stands on a greater edge than even the cliff -- the edge of the dark side. **The earth SHAKES. The earth splits. A gully forms**.
29. Transparent computer display

    Does map display count? Does hologram of Starkiller?

    If that doesn't count, then we have this display showing Starkiller battle, that C-3PO points to saying "The weapon will be fully charged in 10 minutes":

    [image]
30. Sign or display in Aurebesh script

    Yes, many.

    Poe Dameron's quadnoculars on Jakku show Aurebesh in the display, including the word "LOCK". [Wikia has tons of other examples](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_use_of_Aurebesh#Films)

[image: aurebesh binocs]

31. A new Force ability

    Yes. [Kylo Ren **freezes** a blaster bolt (and a person) with a Force](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/114841/why-do-kylo-rens-force-effects-shake/114845#114845).

    He also mind-reads someone, without their will. That is NOT possible in OT, Vader/Emperor [merely sense Luke's thoughts about something emotionally intense](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/111024/976); but Vader can't mind-read Leia when interrogating her.
32. Big "Noooooo!!"

    Yessssssss!.

    - Finn yells "No!" when Rey is taken by Ren from Takodana.

      > Ignoring the fire of retreating stormtroopers, paying no attention to the blasts that gouged the dirt around him, Finn raced toward the shuttle—only to watch helplessly as it lifted off and rose toward the clouds. Irrationally, he tried to follow the dark spot as it rose higher into the sky, running beneath it until it shrank to a dot and then finally disappeared.
      >   **"No, no, no, no…Rey, Rey!"**
    - Rey screams "No!" as Han is stuck with the lightsaber. In the novelization she just whispers, however.

      > "Solo. Solo." Finn put an arm around the girl beside him. "Rey."
      >   **"No," she whispered. "No, no, no…"**
    - Chewie screams something that almost everyone considers to be a Shyriiwook equivalent of a "Nooooo" after Han falls.
33. Someone gets Force choked

    **No**. Not quite.

    Kylo Ren **Force-Flies** an officer (who reported that "a girl" helped BB-8 escape) towards himself, and chokes him with his hand the same exact way Darth Vader choked Captain Antilles on Tantive IV in ANH. But that is NOT a Force Choke.
34. Alien speaks English in an ethnic accent

    I don't think so.

    Didn't notice this myself.

    Didn't find anything on Google.

    The only likely candidates were actually human (Admiral in the Resistance, and gangster Tasu Leech played by Indonesian actor - and he didn't speak "English" but Huttese - see #35).

    Another candidate is Maz Kanata (several commenters said so). I am ESL so I'm not qualified to judge if the actress speaks with an accent - especially one speaking British English :)
35. Alien speaks alien language and Han replies in English

    Yes.

    First of all, Chewbacca. Like, well, D'uh!!!!

    Barring that, if you count Tasu Leech as "alien" despite him being biologically human, that counts too.

    > "Tasu Leech! Good to see you!"
    >   Han knew perfectly well that Tasu Leech would never deign to speak Basic, so he was not surprised when the man replied in another language—one with which Han was, fortunately, familiar. "Wrong again, Solo. It’s over for you, and for your associate." Raising the weapon he held, Leech aimed it down the corridor.
    >
    > "Not now, Chewie! That won’t help." Han took a deep breath. "Guys! You’re all gonna get what I promised. The merchandise is here, the buyer is waiting. I just need to make the delivery. Have I ever not delivered for you before?"
    >   Moving his hands deliberately and slowly, Tasu Leech made a show of activating his weapon. "**Twice**."
    >   Han frowned. Leech was correct, of course, but Han wasn’t about to admit it. "**Twice**?"
36. Someone mentions midi-chlorians

    [NO! No midi-chlorians in Episode VII!](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/112168/976)
37. Lens flare

    [Yes :(  But not Star Trek level](http://www.gamespot.com/gallery/every-lens-flare-in-the-star-wars-the-force-awaken/2900-347/).

    J.J. Abrams [said](http://www.pedestrian.tv/news/arts-and-culture/jj-abrams-promises-to-keep-lens-flare-minimal-in-t/f68c0364-e447-406a-b46a-d01859037b2c.htm):

    > "As you'll see in the Star Wars movie, I've allowed lens flares to take a very backseat [role] ... We're making sure it looks photo-realistic, [because] every time there could be a flare, I said, 'This is not the movie. These are not the flares you're looking for.'"

    For example I noticed lens flare when Ren's lightsaber lights up; or when Falcon flies on Jakku, or when weird ship flies off of Jakku in Rey's Forceback.
38. Clock wipe between scenes

    *??? No idea. Didn't notice any. But Googling for that returns nothing*
39. Line that gets more amusing if you replace "Force" with "pants"

    Being I'm over 5 years old (as per SE's user agreement!), **no**.

    This is really subjective, though.

    But, since I haven't seen any mentions of this while Googling, I'll assume my opinion wins with the silent agreement of entire Internet.
40. Lightsaber used for a non-combat purpose

    Yes. It's used [like LSD for Rey's Forceback. Groovy trip, maaaan](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/111972/976).

    It's also used as a message/relay, by Rey passing it to Luke at the end.
41. R2-D2 falls over

    No. R2 is in very few scenes, mostly powered down. No falling over at all.
42. C-3PO is damaged

    Not onscreen.

    But he has a new red hand from before-screen events left unspecified except that it was a memento of another droid's "sacrifice" as per Visual Dictionary.
43. On-screen kiss

    - One-way only. Rey kisses Finn at the end.

      > A NEW DAY. Finn, unconscious in an I.C.U. POD. His fate uncertain. Rey sits with him. Deeply worried. Finally she leans in, close to him.
      >   **She kisses him** and says, quietly, despite her fear:
      >   REY
      >   We'll see each other again. I believe that. Thank you, my friend.

      Please note that no more kissing happens according to both novelization and WGA script text search.
    - Finn and Rey hug very romantically, till Han advises them to <strike>get a room</strike> "escape first, hug later":

      > INT. STARKILLER BASE - CORRIDOR 6 - DAY
      >   Rey climbs up to the corridor, vigilant. She hears a SOUND, SWOOPS her rifle at -- Finn, Han and Chewie! She cannot believe it! **All Finn wants to do is hug her -- and she him**.
    - Han and Leia hug, but don't kiss.

      > Han places his hands on her shoulders. It could be thirty years ago.

      [image]
44. Someone says "I love you."

    Not in the film or the script or novelization (checked them using text search for "love").

    In the novelization only, Han wants to, but Leia shuts him up before he can. The more I answer TFA questions, the less I like Leia :(

    > He put his hands on her shoulders, and thirty years fell away in an instant. "Leia, there’s something I’ve been wanting to say to you for a long time."
    >   Fighting to hold back tears, she put a finger to his lips. "Tell me when you get back."
45. John Williams score reprises a theme from original trilogy (credits don’t count)

    Yes. A full analysis would far exceed the margins of this post, but plenty of themese reprise, including all the main ones.
46. R2-D2 uses a tool we’ve never seen before

    Does "Sleeping" count? If not, then **no**.

    But his holoprojection of the map is WAY better than "mini-Leia" holo he showed in Episode IV
47. Scene involving food

    Maz's Castle. Visual dictionary actually has details of what food they serve. Yum!

    [image: food]

    > While Finn’s appetite had been sharpened by a trooper’s customary diet of synthsust, it was nothing compared to Rey’s. In spite of himself, he could only marvel at the amount of food the girl downed. It was as if she had never eaten real food in her life. Origins didn’t seem to matter, either. She grabbed and consumed examples of anything within reach without bothering to ascertain its genesis. Han also ate energetically, but he was considerably more decorous.

    Also, Rathtar's eat!

    Also, Rey eats green goo breakfast.
48. Vehicle with legs

    There was a "Base defense walker" on Starkiller base. It is shown off to the right of the plaza where everyone listens to General Hux's speech (Visual Dictionary illustration of that speech has it too).

    [image]
49. Giant monster based on real world insect or other small animal

    - Rathtars seem to be loosely based on Octopii or squids to an extent.
    - Happabore looks like a giant pig. But pigs aren't "insect or small animal" by any means.

    Otherwise, no.
50. Creature that lives in vacuum of space

    No.
51. Jedi mind trick

    Yes. Rey JMTs James Bond.
52. Line repeats never before repeated line from original trilogy

    Yes. Han says that Falcon made Kessel Run in 12 Parsecs.

    > The Millennium Falcon." She could not keep the wonder out of her voice. "**This is the ship that made the Kessel Run in fourteen parsecs.**"
    >   "**Twelve parsecs**." Entering the cockpit ahead of the others, Han scanned the console. A wave of something washed over the Millennium Falcon’s rightful owner (*Novelization*)
    >
    > REY
    >   This is the ship that made the Kessel Run in fourteen parsecs...!
    >   INT. MILLENNIUM FALCON - COCKPIT - SAME
    >   Han enters the cockpit.
    >   HAN
    >   **Twelve! Fourteen**.
53. An escape pod ejects from a ship

    Not from a capital ship.

    But Finn escapes a TIE/sf in an ejection seat (not noted in any text but can see the seat + parachute in the movie).

    Also, while not in the film, a prequel novel "Lost Stars" has the Star Destroyer captain be carried to escape pod and dropped. [That is **the same Star Destroyer** we see Rey looting on Jakku](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/112268/976).
54. Blaster shot ricochets and kills someone

    ??? Not that I could figure out.
55. Bigger than life size hologram

    Yes. Snoke.

[image: snoke hologram]

56. Someone is immune to Jedi mind tricks

    Not quite. James Bond's Stormtrooper is immune on first 2 tries but succumbs on a third.

    And Rey doesn't let Kylo Ren read her mind in the end - but does at the start, and it's NOT really a JMT (different Force Power).
57. Real world unit of measurement (e.g. metres, parsecs)

    Yes.

    > The Millennium Falcon." She could not keep the wonder out of her voice. "**This is the ship that made the Kessel Run in fourteen parsecs.**"
    >   "**Twelve parsecs**." Entering the cockpit ahead of the others, Han scanned the console. A wave of something washed over the Millennium Falcon’s rightful owner
58. Running duel moves from one location to another

    What does that mean? **Yes**, depending on how you define "location".

    We have Finn dueling stormtrooper. Finn dueling Ren. Ren dueling Rey. They all run around like crazy when dueling.

    Plus, we have tons of blaster shootouts that move between locations.
59. Someone foresees the future

    Yes.

    Rey's visions from touching the lightsaber include seeing her in the future on Starkiller, facing Ren in the forest in the snow.

    Also, some people do it using logic, not stupid Jedi tricks.

    - Snoke foresees that Resistance will ASAP search for Luke's planet once they get the map.
    - [Leia foresees that First Order will try to Starfry their base next, in Novelization only](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/45277/235).
60. Someone swings on a rope or vine

    Yes. Rey rappels down a rope inside the Star Destroyer in the film's beginning.
61. Character who died in first six movies mentioned by name

    Yes. "There was too much Vader in him" - Han.

    Also, Snoke and Ren discuss Vader by name in novelization.
62. C-3PO says something about space travel

    No
63. Death of an original trilogy character

    > Han
64. Obvious video game level scene

    This is really too subjective to answer.

    This is Disney so of course **yes**, one doesn't even need to watch the film to be sure.

    Presumably, Takodana fight of FO vs Resistance, or Starkiller fight, would make a good game basis.
65. New alien species obviously designed to appeal to kids

    Another one that's (1) too subjective to answer and (2) the answer is a certain "yes" because Disney.

    BB-8 fills that role. People claim Maz Kanata is one as well.
66. Someone is identified as a clone

    Not quite, but Ren strongly suggests replacing "real" stormtroopers with Clones. Does that count?
67. A bad guy successfully shoots someone

    Yes.

    Stormtroopers shoot a bunch of people, first on Jakku then at the Castle. They also shoot down a bunch of X-Wings :(

    Also, one of the gangsters shoots and wounds Chewie on Eravana.
68. Mooks firing en masse and repeatedly missing

    Gangsters vs. Han. Stormtroopers vs. everyone on Starkiller.
69. Droids walk through a crossfire without getting hit

    No. BB-8 rolls through blasterfire on Jakku with Finn and Rey, but **it was not crossfire**.
70. Sith apprentice kills master

    They discuss Vader vs. Sidious in the dialog in novelization, but otherwise, no.
71. Sith master arranges death of apprentice

    No. But Han mentions to Ben that Snoke will "crush" him when he outlives his usefulness.
72. A droid fixes a spaceship

    Yes. We see a droid helping fix X-Wing on D'Qar.
73. R2-D2 sits in an astromech port in a spaceship

    No. But BB-8 does.
74. Darth X, where X prefixed with "in" is a word

    Vader mentioned. Otherwise, no.

    Unless it ends up that Snoke is Darth Plagueis or Darth Anakin or Darth Palpatine's Ghost :)

---

---

TODOs left to fix if someone wants to ("!!" denotes ones where I don't have a good answer):

**Questions that I don't know the answer to, or don't have a good answer.**

- 34: **!! Need someone with a clue to conclusively decide whether Maz speaks English with an "ethnic" accent. I can't tell**.
- 38: **!! Need to figure out if there's clock wipes**
- 54: **!! No idea what the answer is**
- 62: Someone need to check novelization and script for 100% of C-3PO text
- 64: **!! No idea what the answer is**. Too subjective to answer

**Questions that would REALLY benefit from a screenshot**

- 2: Need screenshots of subtitles as proof
- 33: Need screenshots of Kylo Ren non-force-choking an officer
- 37: Need screenshots of lens flares as proof
- 49: Could use screenshots of Happabore and Rathtar
- 53: Could use screenshot of Finn's ejection seat
- 56: Needs a link to the question discussing Jedi Mind Trick failure on 
  James Bond ST
- 60: Need screenshots of Rey doing Tarzan
- 72: Need screenshots of droid fixing X-Wing on D'Qar.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60024/discussion-on-answer-by-dvk-on-ahch-to-which-predictions-of-the-force-awakens-d).

Answer (score 8):

Despite the naysayers, I think there is a decent enough YES for #39, "Line that gets more amusing if you replace 'Force' with 'pants'"

When Finn, Han & Chewie are breaking into Starkiller,

```
Han: People are counting on us! The galaxy is counting on us--!

Finn: Solo, we'll figure it out! We'll use the Pants!

Han: That's not how the Pants works--!
```

But maybe I just find it amusing to think that they are lugging around some very special pants that have a very defined use (that only Pants adepts, or someone familiar with the Pants, know)

Answer (score 2):

Obviously spoiler alert! Will edit as soon as I can recall more details. Here it is:

1. *Someone gets a hand cut off:* nope, although Kylo Ren was surely close
2. *Someone has a bad feeling about “this”:* Han Solo
3. *BB-8’s head comes off:* nope, apparently the thing works better that expected
4. *C-3PO says how many forms of communication he’s fluent in:* nope, in this movie he is very modest
5. *Wilhelm scream:* yes
6. An alien talks with subtitles
7. *“May the Force be with you.”:* yep, almost sure, but can't remember exactly when
8. *Something is a trap!:* nope
9. *Percussive maintenance on the Millennium Falcon:* no
10. *Chewie welds something:* nope
11. *R2-D2 plugs into a computer terminal socket:* nope, it just projects some holograms
12. *Han shoots someone first:* I'm not sure but maybe the creditors that board the Millennium Falcon
13. *Someone we thought was dead turns out to be alive:* Poe Dameron on Jakku
14. *A Force ghost appears:* nope
15. *Someone constructs a new lightsaber:* not sure
16. *Jar Jar Binks:* nope
17. *A new single biome planet:* yes, Jakku for instance
18. *Hyperdrive malfunction:* yes due to the modification on the Millenium Falcon
19. *A yellow lightsaber:* nope, just blue and red
20. *An alien animal attacks!:* yes, the monsters on the ship of Solo
21. *An asteroid field!:* nope
22. *Lightsaber wield combo more epic than ever seen before:* nope
23. New fighter named after a letter of the alphabet
24. Summon bigger fish!
25. *Someone serving bizarre alien drinks:* not to the main characters, but definitely at Maz Kanata's
26. *Alien band plays music:* maybe at Maz Kanata's?
27. *Vehicle hovers when it would work just as well or better with wheels:* nope
28. *Bottomless pit without a railing:* yes, on the Starkiller Base where Solo falls
29. *Transparent computer display:* maybe the tactical display used at the Resistance headquarters
30. *Sign or display in Aurebesh script:* not that I recall
31. *A new Force ability:* yes, Kylo Ren freezing blaster mid-air
32. *Big “Noooooo!!”:* yes!!! When Kylo Ren kills Solo
33. *Someone gets Force choked:* yes, by Kylo Ren
34. Alien speaks English in an ethnic accent
35. Alien speaks alien language and Han replies in English
36. Someone mentions midi-chlorians
37. Lens flare
38. Clock wipe between scenes
39. Line that gets more amusing if you replace “Force” with “pants’ (hard one this point)
40. *Lightsaber used for a non-combat purpose:* to cut trees while Kylo Ren and Rey fight is valid?
41. *R2-D2 falls over:* nope
42. *C-3PO is damaged:* it has the red arm that needs to be substituted, but no damages taken in the movie
43. *On-screen kiss:* Rey on the forehead of Finn
44. *Someone says “I love you.”:* Han to Leia maybe?
45. John Williams score reprises a theme from original trilogy (credits don’t count)
46. *R2-D2 uses a tool we’ve never seen before:* nope
47. *Scene involving food:* yes at Maz Kanata's tavern
48. *Vehicle with legs:* don't recall any
49. Giant monster based on real world insect or other small animal
50. *Creature that lives in vacuum of space:* nope
51. *Jedi mind trick:* yes Rey with the stormtrooper (the maybe cameo of Daniel Craig)
52. Line repeats never before repeated line from original trilogy
53. *An escape pod ejects from a ship:* yes, to save both Poe Dameron and Finn when they are shoot over Jakku
54. Blaster shot ricochets and kills someone
55. *Bigger than life size hologram:* maybe Leader Snook
56. Someone is immune to Jedi mind tricks
57. Real world unit of measurement (e.g. metres, parsecs)
58. Running duel moves from one location to another
59. Someone foresees the future
60. *Someone swings on a rope or vine:* nope
61. *Character who died in first six movies mentioned by name:* Vader
62. C-3PO says something about space travel
63. *Death of an original trilogy character:* Han Solo
64. Obvious video game level scene
65. *New alien species obviously designed to appeal to kids:* Maz Kanata
66. Someone is identified as a clone
67. A bad guy successfully shoots someone
68. Mooks firing en masse and repeatedly missing
69. Droids walk through a crossfire without getting hit
70. *Sith apprentice kills master:* nope
71. *Sith master arranges death of apprentice:* nope
72. *A droid fixes a spaceship:* nope, no need when there's Rey around
73. *R2-D2 sits in an astromech port in a spaceship:* nope
74. Darth X, where X prefixed with “in” is a word

Comment: Prediction 17 is a yes to me. When Rey arrives to Luke's planet, she says something like "I've never seen so much green".  I take this as meaning that Jakku was a single biome desert planet enough for our purposes.

Comment: 27 is probably just a disagreement about what wheels are good for, but can you clarify about 32?  When did you hear a big Noooooo!!

Comment: @b_jonas thank you, edited

Comment: @b_jonas: Rey say the "so much green" line when they arrive on Takodana (Maz Kanata's planet), not on Luke's planet.

Comment: I disagree with 28: there was a railing on that catwalk. (Also, the answer to 27 is "yes, Rey's speeder", but that's with "snideness filters on", i.e. ignoring the part of the question that's subject to interpretation.)

Comment: @Martha yes it would work with wheels, but on a sandy ground seems to me that hovering could be more efficient, this is why I wrote no

Comment: I haven't seen the movie yet, but I've read tons about it, and everyone agrees that Kylo Ren freezes a blaster bolt in midair, which is clearly a new Force power.  Vader *may* have *absorbed* blaster bolts from Han's blaster in ESB using the Force, or he *may* have simply taken the hit and not suffered any damage because of his armor, but even if the Force was involved there, he didn't **freeze** a blaster bolt in the air.