# Are there other female stormtroopers?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

In *The Force Awakens*, we see that FN-2187's superior, Captain Phasma, is a woman.

Are there other female stormtroopers in any of the other *Star Wars* movies? What do we know about them? Do they have relationships, or children?

Comment: Wasn't the stormtrooper that Kylo Ren said "she's testing her powers" to female? I'd put that as an answer, but I don't have any sources other than my memory.

Comment: Yes, the "she" Kylo Ren meant was Rey, but the stormtrooper was female was well.

Comment: related reading: [is the Empire racist?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/5637/is-the-empire-racist)

Comment: How she got her armor: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zc1__2waAX8

Comment: “In The Force Awakens, we see that FN-2187's superior, Captain Phasma, is a woman.” Actually, do we see that? She definitely *sounds* female to me, but is she ever actually described as “she”?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - she is in the novelization and Visual Dictionary

Comment: Well, we don't actually *see* that Captain Phasma is a woman, we only know Captain Phasma is played by a woman. In fact, [Phasma's armor](http://static.srcdn.com/slir/w700-h400-q90-c700:400/wp-content/uploads/Star-Wars-7-Captain-Phasma-White-and-Chrome-Armors.jpg) isn't even [feminine](http://www.trbimg.com/img-55ce3e8a/turbine/la-et-hc-star-wars-captain-phasma-costume-d23-20150814). It's nearly the same shape with the same contours as normal [Stormtrooper armor](http://static6.techinsider.io/image/5637aa529dd7cc25008c68b4-1703-1277/star-wars-the-force-awakens-stormtroopers.jpg).

Comment: Even [standard Stormtrooper armor in ~0BBY](http://cdn.idigitaltimes.com/sites/idigitaltimes.com/files/styles/image_embed/public/2015/04/16/stormtroopercorps.jpg) was arguably more feminine than Captain Phasma's armor.

Comment: @codemed - added example of female stormtrooper from TFA who isn't Phasma.

Comment: @DVK-on-Ahch-To You better get out of Ahch-To.. It doesn't have enough significance anymore..

Answer (score 19):

### Disney Canon: Empire.

Yes, at least some.

- According to Rebels show, [there were](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Unit_Forn).
- Miller's "A New Dawn" had a female stormtrooper searching a bar (Chapter 22)

  > The female stormtrooper surveyed the cheering crowd.

### Disney Canon: First Order

- Captain Phasma is definitely a stormtrooper (though a bloody officer), so yes.

  She is described as being proficient with weapons **and participates in combat directly**, so she's a "real" stormtrooper, not an armchair general like General Hux.
- Her *Visual Dictionary* page says there were female stormtroopers

  > She pays little heed to the outdated notions of inequality between genders, an idea common on undeveloped worlds. To her thinking, a female stormtrooper is nothing new at all. The anonymity provided by their armour concealed the fact that both men and women served the Galactic Empire as stormtroopers.

  This seems to imply there weren't many female stormtroopers in First Order beside her, if any - which is confirmed by both the novelization (none are mentioned except her) as well as prequel book "Before the Awakening" (same situation).
- In *The Force Awakens*, the stormtroper on Starkiller Base who reports to Ren about Rey's possible location is clearly female judging from the voice, though the WGA script doesn't say so:

  > STORMTROOPER
  >   Sir, sensors triggered in hangar 718. We're searching the area.
- A bit less of an evidence, but we know Imperial service was open to women, including in high positions, even if it was rare.

  - Disney canon had Captain (when she first encountered Kannan in Miller's book) - and later Rear Admiral (by the time of "Aftermath" novel) - Rae Sloane
  - Disney canon ("Lost Stars" E7 prequel) had a [female captain of the Star Destroyer which crashed on Jakku](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/112268/976)
  - EU had Admiral Daala, Tarkin's girlfriend and tactician extraordinair (at least in simulations); and going outside military per se, Intelligence Director Isard.

Comment: Do they have relationships?  Do they have children?  (Knowing they would be raised as the harvested child recruits are raised/programmed)

Comment: @CodeMed - no canon info. You got everything we know in the answer. I'll update if some future canon work introduces better info.

Comment: @CodeMed one piece of anecdotal data we have is that Finn asks Rey if she has to go back to Jakku because she has a "boyfriend? cute boyfriend?".  So he has a functional concept of hetero romantic relationships, which might be hard to develop in an all male environment.

Comment: @zipquincy Thank you.  That is the kind of insight I was seeking with the OP.

Comment: @DVK I was talking about Finn, former stormtrooper, who is not Han and Leia's child??

Comment: @zipquincy - ah, misread your comment, sorry. The prequel novel shows stormtroopers socializing with each other and stuff, as any modern army would.

Comment: @zipquincy - that aside, I still vote that Finn is Han's child from that woman who claimed to be his wife in some obscure EU comic :)

Comment: @DVK so socializing with other male stormtroopers only, socializing with male and female troopers, or socializing with male troopers and female non-troopers?  Also, even if Finn was Han's child, he was taken at birth so he would not remember Han and Leia's relationship.  Having "boyfriend? cute boyfriend?" in his spontaneous vocabulary requires a lot of background understanding of romantic hetero human relationships I would say (at least as much as you can get from 3 words).

Comment: @zipquincy - we simply don't know. Prequel is very short and shows a VERY small slice of life (only 4 stormtroopers are shown and named, aside from Captain Phasma). However, we see female starship captains too.

Comment: We know they are not clones in the VII, as the commander states "I wish I had clones" while the other rebuffs "Our soldiers have training since birth". Finn later explains he was stolen from a family and trained to be a weapon since a very young age.

Comment: Does anyone else remember a stormtrooper with a female voice in The Force Awakens? Besides Phasma, I mean. She has only one or two lines, but I can't recall the details of the scene.

Comment: https://twitter.com/starwars/status/856855331405746177

Comment: Female First Order troopers are mentioned a couple of times in *Phasma*; one of the three troopers accompanying Brendol Hux on Parnassos is female, and Cardinal mentions "boys and girls" when surveying his class of stormtrooper trainees

Comment: There's also [Thara Nyende](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Thara_Nyende) from Alexander Freed's [Battlefront: Twighlight Company](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Battlefront%3A_Twilight_Company) which is considered Canon (as far as I know)

Comment: [**Iden Versio**](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Iden_Versio) from the new battlefront game started as a special forces stormtrooper.  I think they [released a novel](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Battlefront_II:_Inferno_Squad) with her in it, so she may be canon.

Comment: What rank of officer is a *bloody* officer?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, and shown explicitly in more recent canon sources. In an episode of *Rebels* ([In The Name of the Rebellion](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/In_the_Name_of_the_Rebellion)), Ezra, Sabine, and Saw Gerrera board an Imperial freighter transporting a giant kyber crystal--unknown to them, being taken to the under-construction Death Star--and run into a force of Death Troopers that's commanded by a woman, DT-F16, who manages to be the last survivor of the unit.

This is revealed only by her voice (in this case, provided by the go-to voice artist for the female badass, Jennifer Hale).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Star Wars Battlefront Inferno Squad novel featured a female Imperial special force commando name Iden. [image]

Comment: For what it's worth, in the Battlefront II solo player campaign (which is also a canon story), you can overhear assorted Stormtroopers when sneaking around or when in combat and several of the voices are female.

Answer (score -4):

In the previous movies, they were all clones and therefore all males.

However, in this movie, I'm not sure if we must consider her as a stormtrooper or simply as another high lever commander but with a special armor; like Kylo Ren or Darth Vader.

Comment: `In the previous movies, they were all clones and therefore all males` = False. In Ep. 2 and 3 they are clones, but in Ep. 4-7 they are normal humans, [not clones](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/41198/what-canon-evidence-is-there-that-stormtroopers-are-are-not-still-clones).

Comment: Hum, I'm not sure if we can say that from the movies only if we exclude the EU which is no longer part of the official canon.  In the movies, there is still this slight difference in height but even identical tweens (I'm not talking about fraternal tweens here) can have minor or even major height differences and this, even when they are raised in the same environment. It's a myth that for an army of clones, they should all have exactly the same height.  For the rest, you're right, some fans consider that in ep. 4-6, they are normal humans; not clones.  For ep.7, this is another question.

Comment: Star Wars: Rebels, which is fully canon has shown that at least *some* stormtroopers post-CW are non-clones. We don't know that the squads we saw going through training were the norm or unique, though.

Comment: I have not seen the Star Wars: Rebels but it's understandable that in such a serie, the clones are no longer clones.  After all, that's the point of creating a new serie: it's to create new stories and therefore, to make things complicated where they were simple before.  However, the original question is about female stormtroopers; therefore, have you seen any female stormtroopers in Rebels?  Furthermore, the original poster should tell us if it's interested only in the movies (like me) or if he/she would like to take into account the latest full canon. (At least, until they change it again.)