# Why do Kylo Ren's force effects shake?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, the-force, kylo-ren

I've seen the discussions about the cracked crystal in Kylo Ren's light saber causing it's shaky appearance, but why do his other force effects wobble and shake?

Near the start of the film, he freezes a blaster bolt and it hangs in the air shaking.

When he uses the force to freeze people, they shake.

I don't remember anything like this in the other movies. I haven't seen many of the Clone Wars shows, so I don't know if there's a precedent there either.

Clearly Kylo Ren is strong in the force (I don't recall Vader ever freezing a blaster bolt, just deflecting them. Maybe he just didn't want to), but is the shakiness a sign of his lack of training? Is he using brute force rather than finesse?

(The obvious out of universe answer is that it just looks cooler, but I'm wondering if there's an actual in universe answer.)

Comment: Because it looks cooler.  Also, because it is possible to make it happen onscreen now.

Answer (score 3):

- Blaster Bolt: this is clearly an advanced technique, **not even known to any Sith we are aware of** before Kylo Ren.

  I for one won't dock points from Ren, even if the vibration is due to imperfections of that more-advanced-than-Sidious technique. 10.0, 10.0, and 10.1 from East German judge.

  But it's also possible that it's an artistic decision, to show that he's actually HOLDING the blast with a power of his will, as you would a striking blade when blocking it - as opposed to flawed technique. Neither the script nor novelization nor Visual Dictionary discuss the cause.

  > Kylo Ren RAISES HIS HAND -- POE'S BLAST FREEZES -- THE BOLT
  >   OF ENERGY STRAINING AND VIBRATING IN MID AIR!
  >   (*WGA leaked script*)
- People shaking: that is likely deliberate. It shows visually what the script/novelization describe their frantic attempts (especially Poe and Ren) to free themselves.

  > Kylo Ren sees Poe, who suddenly **CANNOT MOVE, but strains to**.
  >   He is grabbed by Stormtroopers who drag him past the
  >   VIBRATING, FROZEN BLAST, to Kylo Ren.

  ...

  > Kylo Ren TURNS OFF HIS SABER, reaches up... and REACHES
  >   TOWARDS REY'S FACE. She can't move, **strains in agony**.

Comment: And a 4.0 from the Russians!