# Who are these people at Deadpool's wedding?

Tags: marvel, comics, character-identification, deadpool

[image]

Who are these people, and what universes are they from?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

There is a marvel guide picture for it and shows count of 236, contrary to my [own comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/119845/who-are-these-people-at-deadpools-wedding#comment293004_119845)

[image]

With inspiration from [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Marvel/comments/1ubgqm/marvels_upcoming_wedding_guestlist_help_me/), manual eyeballing, and the help of [Julian](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35910/discussion-between-ankit-sharma-and-julian), below is the list of characters seen in the wedding:-

1. [Devil Dinosaur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devil_Dinosaur)
2. [Snowbird](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snowbird_(comics))
3. [Moon Boy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moon-Boy)
4. [Shaman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shaman_(comics))
5. [Sasquatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sasquatch_(comics))
6. [Guardian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guardian_(Marvel_Comics))
7. [Northstar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northstar)
8. [Aurora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aurora_(comics))
9. [Vindicator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vindicator_(comics))
10. [Marrina](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marrina_Smallwood)
11. [Pixie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixie_(comics))
12. [Starfox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starfox_(comics))
13. [The White Tiger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_Tiger_(Ava_Ayala))
14. [Union Jack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_Jack_(comics))
15. [Collective Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collective_Man)
16. [Spitfire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spitfire_(comics))
17. [Giant-Man / Hank Pym](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giant-Man)
18. [Vision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vision_(Marvel_Comics))
19. [Collective Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collective_Man)
20. [Alexis](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Alexis_(Earth-616))
21. [The Silver Surfer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silver_Surfer)
22. [The Red Guardian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Guardian)
23. [D-man](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=d-mannose&oq=d-man&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57j0l4.1079j0j4&client=ubuntu-browser&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=d-man)
24. [Velocidad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velocidad_(comics))
25. [Quicksilver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksilver_(comics))
26. [Transonic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transonic_(comics))
27. [Wiccan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiccan_(comics))
28. [Lucky in The Sky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karolina_Dean)
29. [Groot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groot)
30. [Prodigy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prodigy_(comics))
31. [Drax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drax_the_Destroyer)
32. [Gamora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamora)
33. [Mantis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mantis_(Marvel_Comics))
34. [Collective Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collective_Man)
35. [The original angel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warren_Worthington_III)
36. [Ghost Rider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghost_Rider_(comics))
37. [Madrox The Multiple Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jamie_Madrox)
38. [Madrox The Multiple Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jamie_Madrox)
39. [Madrox The Multiple Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jamie_Madrox)
40. [Scarlet Spider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scarlet_Spider)
41. [Quasar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasar_(comics))
42. [Jim_Hammond The First Human Torch](http://marvel.com/universe/Human_Torch_(Jim_Hammond))
43. [Venom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venom_(comics))
44. [Colleen Wing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colleen_Wing)
45. [Misty Knight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Misty_Knight)
46. [Chod](http://comicvine.gamespot.com/chod/4005-40789/)
47. [Cr'ree](http://comicvine.gamespot.com/crreee/4005-10304/forums/)
48. [Darkhawk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darkhawk)
49. [Star Lord](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star-Lord)
50. [B'nee Warstar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warstar)
51. [C'cil Warstar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warstar)
52. [Gravity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_(comics))
53. [The Fin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fin_(comics))
54. [3-D Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-D_Man)
55. [Nighthawk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nighthawk_(Marvel_Comics))
56. [Rage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rage_(comics))
57. [Tigra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tigra)
58. [Scintilla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Marvel_Comics_characters:_S#Scintilla)
59. [Starbolt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starbolt)
60. [Neuron](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Neuron_(Earth-101001))
61. [Oracle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_(Marvel_Comics))
62. [Mentor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mentor_(A%27lars))
63. [Earthquake](https://www.marvel.com/characters/earthquake)
64. [Fang](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Fang_(Imperial_Guard)_(Earth-616))
65. [Electron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_(comics))
66. [Manta](http://marvel.com/universe/Manta)
67. [Hussar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hussar_(comics))
68. [Pulsar (also known as Impulse)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulsar_(Marvel_Comics))
69. [Fin Fang Foom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fin_Fang_Foom)
70. [The Watcher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watcher_(comics))
71. [Red Raven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Raven_(Marvel_Comics))
72. [Stingray](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stingray_(comics))
73. [Dust](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dust_(comics))
74. [The Shroud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shroud_(comics))
75. [Hobgoblin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hobgoblin_(comics))
76. [Astra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astra_(comics))
77. [Gladiator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gladiator_(Kallark))
78. [Man-Thing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-Thing)
79. [Amadeus Cho](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amadeus_Cho)
80. [Shanna the She-Devil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shanna_the_She-Devil)
81. [Son of Satan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daimon_Hellstrom)
82. Eye-Robot
83. [The Champion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Champion_of_the_Universe)
84. [Red Hulk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunderbolt_Ross#Red_Hulk_reception)
85. [Sif](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sif_(comics))
86. [Valkyrie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valkyrie_(Marvel_Comics))
87. [Fandral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fandral)
88. [Hogun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hogun)
89. [Volstagg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volstagg)
90. [Beta Ray Bill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_Ray_Bill)
91. [Odin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odin_(comics))
92. [Hercules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hercules_(Marvel_Comics))
93. [Balder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balder_(comics))
94. [Thor-Girl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thor_Girl)
95. [Machine Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_Man)
96. [Daredevil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daredevil_(Marvel_Comics))
97. [Spider-Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Man)
98. [Darla Deering](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Darla_Deering_(Earth-616))
99. [Lockjaw](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockjaw_(comics))
100. [Hairball](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Hairball)
101. [Frog Thor](http://comicvine.gamespot.com/throg/4005-30596/)
102. [Ms. Lion](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Ms._Lion_(Earth-97161))
103. [Onome](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Onome_(Earth-616))
104. [Alex Power](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Alexander_Power_(Earth-616))
105. [Tong](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Tong_(Moloid)_(Earth-616))
106. [Korr](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Korr_(Moloid)_(Earth-616))
107. [Mik](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Mik_(Moloid)_(Earth-616))
108. [Sunspot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunspot_(comics))
109. [Forbush Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forbush_Man)
110. [Captain Universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_Universe)
111. [Hawkeye](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawkeye_(comics))
112. [Photon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monica_Rambeau)
113. [Manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eden_Fesi)
114. [Black Panther](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Panther_(comics))
115. [Captain Marvel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_Marvel_(Marvel_Comics))
116. [Smasher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smasher)
117. [Abyss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abyss_(comics))
118. [Falcon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falcon_(comics))
119. [Hyperion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperion_(comics))
120. [Starbrand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Brand)
121. [Nightmask](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Adam_(Nightmask)_(Earth-616))
122. [M-11](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/M-11_(Earth-616))
123. [Namora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namora)
124. [Venus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venus_(Marvel_Comics))
125. [Jimmy Woo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jimmy_Woo)
126. [Gorilla Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gorilla-Man)
127. [Black Swan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Swan_(comics))
128. [Wu](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Wu_(Earth-616))
129. [Vil](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Vil_(Earth-616))
130. [Dragon Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_Man)
131. [Iceman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iceman_(comics))
132. [Nova](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nova_(Sam_Alexander))
133. [Havok](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Havok_(comics))
134. [Rogue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rogue_(comics))
135. [Storm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Storm_(Marvel_Comics))
136. [Captain Britain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_Britain)
137. [Meggan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meggan)
138. [Gargoyle](http://marvel.com/universe/Gargoyle_(Isaac_Christians))
139. [Sunfire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunfire_(comics))
140. [The Scarlet Witch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scarlet_Witch)
141. [Wonder Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wonder_Man)
142. [The Beast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beast_(comics))
143. [Namor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namor)
144. [Blue Marvel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Marvel_(Marvel_Comics))
145. [Iron Fist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron_Fist_(comics))
146. [Quentin Quire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quentin_Quire)
147. [Kid Gladiator](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Kid_Gladiator)
148. [Honey Lemon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honey_Lemon)
149. [Gorgon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gorgon_(Inhuman))
150. [Karnak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnak_(comics))
151. [Black Bolt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Bolt)
152. [Triton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triton_(comics))
153. [Cannonball](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cannonball_(comics))
154. [Ex Nihilo](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Ex_Nihilo_(Earth-616))
155. [Dagger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloak_and_Dagger_(comics))
156. [Cloak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloak_and_Dagger_(comics))
157. [Jubilee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jubilee_(comics))
158. [Shogo](http://comicvine.gamespot.com/shogo/4005-90467/)
159. [Psylocke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psylocke)
160. [Benjamin Deeds](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Benjamin_Deeds_(Earth-616))
161. [Fabio Medina](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Fabio_Medina_(Earth-616))
162. [Magneto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magneto_(comics))
163. [Eva Bell](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Eva_Bell_(Earth-616))
164. [Cyclops](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclops_(comics))
165. [Emma Frost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emma_Frost)
166. [Elsa Bloodstone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elsa_Bloodstone)
167. [Kitty Pryde](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kitty_Pryde)
168. [Lockheed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_(comics))
169. [The Thing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fantastic_Four#Characters)
170. [Human Torch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fantastic_Four#Characters)
171. [Invisible Woman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fantastic_Four#Characters)
172. [Mr. Fantastic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fantastic_Four#Characters)
173. [Medusa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medusa_(comics))
174. [Crystal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_(comics))
175. [Yondu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yondu)
176. Raunak
177. [Moon Knight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moon_Knight)
178. [Spider-Woman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Woman)
179. [Anarchist](http://marvel.com/universe/Anarchist)
180. [Doop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doop_(comics))
181. The original Cyclops
182. The original Marvel Girl
183. The original Iceman
184. The original Beast
185. [Rachel Summers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rachel_Summers)
186. [Magik](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magik_(comics))
187. [Colossus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colossus_(comics))
188. [The Stepford Cuckoos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stepford_Cuckoos)
189. [The Stepford Cuckoos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stepford_Cuckoos)
190. [The Stepford Cuckoos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stepford_Cuckoos)
191. [Triage](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Christopher_Muse_(Earth-616))
192. [Broo](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Broo_(Earth-616))
193. [Iron Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron_Man)
194. [Thor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thor_(Marvel_Comics))
195. [Franklin Richards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Franklin_Richards)
196. [Val Richards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valeria_Richards)
197. [Ant-Man (Scott Lang)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ant-Man_(Scott_Lang))
198. [Brian Posehn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brian_Posehn)
199. [Scott Koblish](http://comicvine.gamespot.com/scott-koblish/4040-4795/)
200. [Val Staples](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Val_Staples)
201. [Axel Alonso](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axel_Alonso)
202. [Mike Hawthorne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mike_Hawthorne)
203. [Dr. Strange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_Strange)
204. [The Hulk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hulk_(comics))
205. [The Impossible Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impossible_Man)
206. [Squirrel Girl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squirrel_Girl)
207. [Lady Deadpool](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Wanda_Wilson_(Earth-3010))
208. [Siryn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siryn)
209. [Domino](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domino_(comics))
210. [The Wasp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wasp_(comics))
211. [Captain America](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_America)
212. [Wolverine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolverine_(character))
213. [The Bride](http://comicvine.gamespot.com/shiklah/4005-97443/) **(Spoiler Alert)**
214. [Deadpool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadpool)
215. [Cable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cable_(comics))
216. [Nightcrawler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nightcrawler_(comics))
217. [She-Hulk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/She-Hulk)
218. [Luke Cage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luke_Cage)
219. [Declan Shalvey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declan_Shalvey)
220. [Jordie Bellaire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordie_Bellaire)
221. [Gerry Duggan](http://marvel.com/comics/creators/11680/gerry_duggan)
222. [Zombie Headpool](http://deadpool.wikia.com/wiki/Headpool)
223. [Widget](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Widget_(Marvel_Comics))
224. [Rocket Raccoon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rocket_Raccoon)
225. [Leech](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leech_(comics))
226. [Artie](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Arthur_Maddicks_(Earth-616))
227. [Danielle Jones-Cage](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Danielle_Cage_(Earth-616))
228. [Jessica Jones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jessica_Jones)
229. [Jordan White](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Jordan_D._White)
230. [Evil Deadpool](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Wade_Wilson_(Evil_Deadpool)_(Earth-616))
231. [Monkey Joe](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Monkey_Joe_(Earth-616))
232. [Dogpool](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Wade_Wilson_(Earth-103173))
233. [Krakoa](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Krakoa_(Earth-616))
234. [Katie Power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Katie_Power)
235. [Jack Power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack_Power)
236. [Puck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puck_(comics))

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35910/discussion-between-ankit-sharma-and-julian).

Comment: One reason for the difference in total is that the multiple men only count as one character.

Comment: In the chat, I just posted Immortal Blues picture for you. You can credit him too :)

Comment: @Julian added your uploaded picture too but which credit link is for that image?

Comment: Is Nightcrawler conducting the ceremony? Don't know much about him. Is he an ordained minister?

Comment: @maguirenumber6 i don't know about it either. Anyways the whole marriage looks like having no sense and for fun only.

Comment: Bounty truly earned!!

Comment: @maguirenumber6 Nightcrawler is a devout Catholic who has studied to become a priest, but circumstances prevented him from finishing his studies. While not an ordained minister, to my knowledge he is the only Marvel character who has tried to become one. ([Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nightcrawler_(comics)#Characteristics) has more info)

Comment: That's a great fact :-)