# Who/What are the characters on this AD 2222 Cyberpunk poster?

Tags: character-identification, crossovers

There is this new [AD 2222 - Giant Cyberpunk Character Poster](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/elephantplayingcards/ad-2222-giant-cyberpunk-character-poster) by *Egor Klyuchnyk*, the same artist who created the [Universe: 113 Character Poster](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/171218/can-we-identify-all-the-characters-in-this-universe-113-poster/).

> On this one poster are illustrated over **200 widely known characters, vehicles and items**.

Can we spot them all?

[image: AD 2222 - Giant Cyberpunk Character Poster]

Added a grid to the image, to easily locate the characters:

[image: AD 2222 - Giant Cyberpunk Character Poster - with grid]

Comment: IMHO, this is not the kind of question belonging here. More appropriate would be something like 'don' t know this character. Who is it? '

Comment: @Shade those questions are very much on-topic, albeit demanding of a lot of work; see for instance [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/119845/98028), [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/171218/98028), [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/195553/98028)...

Comment: Link to a [bigger version](https://i.imgur.com/cIK5a7o.jpg) of the image, from the imgur collection linked in the kickstarter page.

Comment: I don't know about all of them, but I found Waldo!  Three of him, in fact, maybe four.  (H4-H5)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Trying to make this more grid friendly. Question marks by uncertain

A3: Revenant (*DOOM*)
A5: Tallboy (*Dishonored*)
A6: Motoko Kusanagi (*Ghost in the Shell*)
A8: Viper (*XCOM (newer versions)*)
A9: Machete (*Machete*)

B4: Neo (*The Matrix*)
B5: Combine Soldier (*Half Life 2*)
B9: Soviet Airship (*Red Alert 2* & *Red Alert 3*)

C5: Lupin III

D7: Buddy Christ (*Dogma movie*)
D7: Drone (*Oblivion*)
D7: Black Magic M-66

E1: Blade Runner spinner
E1: Batman 
E5: fat guy (*Pearl Jam* - "Do the Evolution")
E9: Predator

F4: Professor Xavier (*newer X-Men movies*)
F4: Consuela de la Morrela (*Family Guy*)
F5: Meg (*Family Guy*)
F5: Princess Leia (*Star Wars*)(Dressed as Chihiro from *Spirited Away*)
F6: Jabba the Hutt (*Star Wars*)
F7: Norbert Foster Beaver  (*The Angry Beavers*)
F8: Daggett Beaver  (*The Angry Beavers*)

G1: Bat signal (*Batman*)
G1: Greymon (*Digimon*)
G2: Brian (*Family Guy*)
G4: Abathur (*Starcraft II*)
G4: Jax (*Mortal Kombat*)
G5: Alien tail? (*Alien*)
G5: Necronomicon
G5: Puzzle Box (*Hellraiser*)
G5: Afro Samurai
G6: Rainbow Dash  (*My Little Pony*)
G6: Roger (*American Dad*)
G7: sentry guns (*Portal*)
G7: Darkwing Duck (*Darkwing Duck*)
G8: Bobba Fett (*Star Wars*)

H1: Greymon (*Digimon*)
H2: Khanivore (*Sonnie's Edge - Love, Death & Robots*)
H2: Shendu The Talisman Dragon (*Jackie Chan Adventures*)
H4: Ghost dubbing machine (*Ghost in the Shell*)
H4: Wally/Waldo (In the ghost dubbing machine)(*Where's Wally?*)
H5: Riddick
H5: Vincent Vega (*Pulp Fiction*)
H8: Boh (*Spirited Away*) but with the head of Porco Rosso (*Porco Rosso*)
H8: Elevator  (*The Fifth Element*)
H9: Ashitaka (*Princess Mononoke*)
H9: corrupted boar god Nago (*Princess Mononoke*) but with the head of No-Face (*Spirited Away*)

I1: Aang (*Avatar*)
I2: Joi (*Blade Runner*)
I2: Catbus (*My Neighbor Totoro*)
I3: standard appartment  (*The Fifth Element*)
I4: Lois Griffin  (*Family Guy*)
I5: Martians (*Mars Attacks*)
I5: Ultramarine (*Warhammer 40K*)
I5: health and suit charging stations (*Half-Life 2*)
I6: Kenny (*South Park*)
I6: Spike Spiegel (*Cowboy Bebop*)
I6: Patrick (*Spongebob Squarepants*)
I6: Storm Tallon? (*Warhammer 40k*) also I7 and J6 
I8: Steven Universe (*Steven Universe*)
I8: a Tamagotchi on a display case
I8: the head of a Laputa droid (*Castle in the Sky*)
I8: a VHS tape on a display case
I9: Stuart (Despicable Me; Minions)
I9: Earthworm Jim
I9: Cortana (*Halo*)
I9: Astro Boy
I9: Stewie Griffin (*Family Guy*)
I9: Phineas (*Phineas and Ferb*)
I9: a Nintendo Wii and a Playstation on a display case
I9: skull of a Xenomorph (Alien)

J1: Alien (*The Simpsons*)
J1: Shelob (*The Lord of the Rings*)
J2: Kenshiro (*Fist of the North Star*)
J4: Sonic (*Sonic the Hedgehog*)
J4: Johnny Bravo (*Johnny Bravo*)
J5: red skeleton (*Mars Attacks*)
J5: Fry, Leela? (*Futurama*) and the head of the Duracell Bunny?? 
J6: John McClane  (*Die Hard*)? 
J7: Gizmo  (*Gremlins*)
J8: Diane (*Seven Deadly Sins* anime)
J9: Ferb (*Phineas and Ferb*)

K2: worm (*Worms* videogames)
K3: Time travel hole (*Terminator*)? 
K4: Tetsuo (*Akira*)

L2: Bender (*Futurama*)
L3: flag of the mobile infantry (*starship troopers*)
L5: Lobby Shooting Scene  (*The Matrix*)
L6: Kel Thuzad (*Warcraft*)
L8: Food Junk (*The Fifth Element*)

M1: Ash Ketchum (*Pokemon*)
M4: Briareos Hecatonchires (*Appleseed*)
M6: Kratos (*God of War*)
M6: time train (*Back to the Future*)
M7: Devilman (*Devilman*)?
M8: Dr. Zoidberg (*Futurama*)
M9: Eva 01 (*Neon Genesis Evangelion*)

N1: Radish Spirit (*Spirited Away)*
N1: Tachikoma (*Ghost in the Shell*)
N5: Armored Titan (*Attack on Titan*)
N6: Butcher (and the baby with laser eyes) (*The Boys*)
N6: Isaac Clarke (*Dead Space*)
N7: Finn and Jake (*Adventure Time*)
N8: Gadget Hackwrench(*Chip and Dale's Rescue Rangers* and *Ducktales*)

O1: Rocco (*Rocco's Modern Life*)
O2: Twayne Boneraper (*Ugly Americans*)
O3: The Loc-Nar (name only, *Heavy Metal* animated movie)
O4: "Caste" graffiti (*Half-Life 2*)
O4: "El Barto" Graffito  (*Simpsons*)
O6: Edward Elric (*Full Metal Alchemist*)
O6: Kumamon
O6: The Knight (*Hollow Knight*)
O7: Gundam (*Mobile Suit Gundam*)
O8: Metal Gear Rex (*Metal Gear Solid*)

P1: Vash the Stampede (*Trigun*)
P3: Aperture Labs (*Portal*)
P3: Wolverine (*X-Men*)
P6: Samus Aran (*Metroid*)
P6: Spiderman 
P8: "Obey Giant" by *Shepard Fairey*
P8: Tom (*Tom and Jerry*)
P9: Chris Griffin (*Family Guy*)

Q1: Strider (*Half Life 2*)
Q1: Hellboy (*Hellboy*)
Q2: Dark Sun Gwyndolin (*Dark Souls*)
Q3: Link (*The Legend of Zelda*)
Q3: Ghostbusters symbol
Q5: Half Life reaction chamber (also Q6)
Q6: Cacodemon (*Doom*)
Q7: Peter Griffin (*Family Guy*)
Q7: blue Graffito "San Fiero Rifa" (*Grand Theft Auto San Andreas*)
Q8: orange Graffito "Los Santos Vagos" (*Grand Theft Auto*)

R4: Canti (*FLCL*)
R8: Wilson (*Don't Starve*)

Comment: A9/B9 appears to be Machete (Danny Trejo) from *Machete*

Comment: I sorta thought the J5 rabbit looked like Peppy Hare

Answer (score 1):

Zoidberg, an oscar meyer weinermobile with a ghostbusters logo, and that tv-headed robot guy from Fooly Cooly.

Buddy Jesus from Dogma, ghost in the shell, Lupin the III, Catbus, an  Elder Thing, Aperture Labs, Finn from Adventure Time, Link and Wolverine, Bruce Willis against the wall (as a Meat Popsicle), Brian the dog, Jabba the Hutt, and a They Live Obey sign featuring Master Shake.

Comment: Could someone with privileges please make this answer a Community Wiki? :)

Comment: Only a mod or yourself can do that (barring lots of edits from multiple users, I forget the threshold). I believe you need to [register your account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/44557/345161) first though.

Comment: Also this would be better if you stated _where_ in the image these characters are.

Answer (score -1):

A5 - Tallboy (Dishonored)

I4 - Summerween Trickster (Gravity Falls)

I9 - Stewie Griffin (Family Guy)

L5, L7 - terrorists (Counter-Strike)

Q2-R2 - Dark Sun Gwyndolin (Dark Souls)

R3 - Tommy Vercetti from GTA Vice City

F2, I4, N2 - graffiti that looks similar to gang tags from GTA San Andreas

Comment: One of the answers here is a community wiki, you should edit that one instead of posting your own partial answer. However, nice finds!