# Names of all the spacecrafts on the art by Philippe “Manchu" Bouchet

Tags: object-identification

I just saw @retroscifiart's [tweet](https://twitter.com/retroscifiart/status/1195618304418697216) with a neat illustration with lots of spaceships from different movies. Art by Philippe “Manchu" Bouchet.

Some of the spaceships are familiar for me, but not all. I would like to know about all of them.

To make it simple, I've added numbers to the image.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1: EVA pod from *2001, A Space Odyssey*

2: the [Space Ark](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pKSO-b-xJ08) from the 1951 movie *When Worlds Collide*

3: Lingan's ship from a 1938 *Flash Gordon comic*

4: [*Sulaco* from *Aliens*](https://www.flickr.com/photos/modelsbychris/43264124231)

5: Vorlon biotech ship from *Babylon 5*

6: Earth Alliance Starfury from *Babylon 5*

7: *Millennium Falcon* from *Star Wars*

8: *Orion III spaceplane* from *2001: A Space Odyssey*

9: [*The Luna*](https://www.flickr.com/photos/57440551@N03/26190454967) from the 1950 movie *Destination Moon*

10: [The Cosmostrator](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07F129B1S) from the 1960 movie [*First Spaceship on Venus*](https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/first_spaceship_on_venus)

11: Eagle transporter from *Space 1999*

12: Naboo starfighter from *Star Wars*

13: [*Narcissus*](https://alienseries.wordpress.com/2013/02/04/narcissus/) (*Nostromo's* escape pod) from *Alien*

14: UFO from *The Invaders*

15: *USS Enterprise-A* from the *Star Trek* movies

16: X-Wing starfighter from *Star Wars*

17: Shadow "battlecrab" from *Babylon 5*

Comment: In keeping with previous "spot the character" questions such as [this one](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/220860), I've marked this answer "community wiki" so that anyone can edit in the answers that they know.

Comment: Is #10 [Liberator from *Blakes 7*](https://www.google.com/search?q=liberator+blakes+7&client=firefox-b-d&source=lnms&tbm=isch)? Similar shape, but I think not exactly the same? It's hard to tell. I haven't edited it in.

Comment: I've changed #4, I believe the *Sulaco* is a better match than the original proposal of an Earth Alliance Battlecruiser from B5.

Comment: Perhaps #13 is the Narcissus from Alien?

Comment: #13 - The Ghost; https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Ghost?

Comment: #10 - Mk3 Thunderbolt Star Fury; https://babylon5.fandom.com/wiki/SA-32A_Mitchell-Hyundyne_Starfury?file=Thunderbolt.jpg

Comment: #2 the space ark from [When Worlds Collide](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0044207/mediaviewer/rm1766230017).

Comment: The numberles one is, of course, the monolith from _2001_. I don't know what #3 is, but its marking says 174, in case that rings a bell.

Comment: Wow! Just several hours and all the ships are identified! Thank you for such an awesome work!

Comment: Presumably it’s specifically the monolith (“doubly inappropriately”) called Tycho Magnetic Anomaly 2 (TMA-2), the giant monolith found in Saturn orbit (retconned to Jupiter orbit in the movie and sequels).

Answer (score 2):

No. 4 is the Sulaco from ALIENS.

[image: Model of the USS Sulaco]

From the Fandom Article on the [USS Sulaco](https://avp.fandom.com/wiki/USS_Sulaco)

Comment: #3 looks pretty Flash Gordon-y, maybe comic strip rather than 1930s serial or 1980 movie.

Comment: That is a comment, not an answer. An try to support your answers. I.e., say why it is as you state.

Comment: Since you are new here you don't that we do not like single answers to a list ID question. We create a single answer that any contributor can edit to fill in the blanks.

Comment: Why has this been marked down? It answers the question and provides evidence and a link with further information. Looks good to me.

Answer (score 2):

Number 3 appears to be "Lingan's ship" from a [1938 Flash Gordon comic](https://artcontrarian.blogspot.com/2013/06/1930s-spaceships.html) (scroll down to the 6th picture):

[image: Yellow spaceship departing Mingo]

Illustration by [Alex Raymond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alex_Raymond).

Comment: Wow! How have you manged to find it out?

Comment: Google Images "flash gordon spaceship comic"