# Who are the characters on this Legend of Zelda poster?

Tags: character-identification, the-legend-of-zelda

I found this poster of various characters from the Legend of Zelda games:

[image]

(click for full size)

Who are they and what game(s) they're from?

Comment: The guy dressed like Tinkerbell with the sword is Link.

Comment: Insanely long video answer to go with your insanely long question. Get typing if you want...["All characters identified!! - AG+ Painting for the 25th Aniversary of Zelda; (Alessio)"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UHnvFiniI_0)

Comment: ... a task worth of the holder of the Triforce of courage indeed. No, really, there is no way I am going numbering and listing all of them.

Comment: @Valorum I thought that's Zel... nope I can't do it... The video's a good start but the font's a bit unreadable at some parts, sadly.

Comment: @Relix - I found it pretty legible throughout.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using [this numbered version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6F39h.jpg) of the image (which is huge, and I couldn't find an easy way to scale down in the post) as a reference, here's the complete list (some answers from the older games taken from [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UHnvFiniI_0)):

1. Three figures that are extremely blurry. Given their positioning and the number of them, I'd guess they're meant to be the three Goddesses (mentioned in legends in pretty much all the games): Nayru, Farore and Din
2. Kaepora Gaebora from *Ocarina of Time* (and other games)
3. Rauru from *Ocarina of Time*
4. Impa from *Ocarina of Time*
5. Saria from *Ocarina of Time*
6. Supposedly the King of Hyrule, though not sure from which game
7. Nabooru from *Ocarina of Time*
8. Princess Ruto (adult) from *Ocarina of Time*
9. Darunia from *Ocarina of Time*
10. Link from all games, though most closely resembles the one from *Twilight Princess*
11. Princess Zelda from all games, though again seems to most closely resemble the one from *Twilight Princess*
12. Ganondorf
13. Wind Fish
14. Great Fairy from *Wind Waker*

    Unnumbered Fairy next to the Great Fairy: possibly Ciela from *Phantom Hourglass*
15. Great Fairy from *Twilight Princess*
16. Great Fairy from *Majora's Mask* (also from *Ocarina of Time*, since they shared character models, but she's holding the Great Fairy Sword that is specific to *Majora's Mask*)
17. Valoo from *Wind Waker*
18. Fi from *Skyward Sword*
19. Presumably Navi from *Ocarina of Time*
20. Tatl (Link's companion fairy) from *Majora's Mask*
21. Tael from *Majora's Mask*
22. The Great Deku Tree from *Ocarina of Time*
23. Fado from *Wind Waker*
24. Deku Tree Sprout from *Ocarina of Time*
25. Makar from *Wind Waker*
26. Fairy Queen from *Wind Waker*
27. Medli from *Wind Waker*
28. Laruto from *Wind Waker*
29. Lord Jabu-Jabu from *Ocarina of Time*
30. Renado from *Twilight Princess*
31. Rusl from *Twilight Princess*
32. Ashei from *Twilight Princess*
33. Shad from *Twilight Princess*
34. Auru from *Twilight Princess*
35. Tarin from *Link's Awakening*
36. Marin from *Link's Awakening*
37. Ilia from *Twilight Princess*
38. Epona from most games, though appears to most closely resemble Epona from *Twilight Princess*
39. Talon from *Ocarina of Time*
40. Ingo from *Ocarina of Time*
41. Anju from *Majora's Mask*
42. Kafei from *Majora's Mask*
43. Linebeck from *Phantom Hourglass*
44. Tetra from *Wind Waker*
45. Gonzo from *Wind Waker*
46. Senza from *Wind Waker*
47. Nudge from *Wind Waker*
48. Tijo from *Majora's Mask*
49. Tingle from *Majora's Mask* (and other games)
50. Cremia from *Majora's Mask*
51. Niko from *Wind Waker*
52. Zuko from *Wind Waker*
53. (Link's) Grandmother from *Wind Waker*
54. Evan from *Majora's Mask*
55. Toto from *Majora's Mask*
56. Lulu from *Majora's Mask*
57. Romani from *Majora's Mask*
58. Ralph from *Oracle of Ages*
59. Mako from *Wind Waker*
60. Maple from *Oracle of Ages*
61. Darmani III from *Majora's Mask*
62. Japas from *Majora's Mask*
63. Mikau from *Majora's Mask*
64. Skull Kid from *Majora's Mask*
65. Mido from *Ocarina of Time*
66. Goron Elder from *Majora's Mask*
67. Goron Elder's son from *Majora's Mask*
68. Deku King from *Majora's Mask*
69. Deku Princess from *Majora's Mask* (with Link in Deku form?)
70. Deku Butler from *Majora's Mask*
71. King of Red Lions from *Wind Waker*
72. Byrne from *Spirit Tracks*
73. Anjean from *Spirit Tracks*
74. Midna from *Twilight Princess*
75. Oshus from *Phantom Hourglass*
76. Sahasrahla from *A Link to the Past*
77. Ezlo from *The Minish Cap*
78. Travelling Mask Salesman from *Majora's Mask*
79. Bellum from *Phantom Hourglass*
80. Veran from *Oracle of Ages*
81. Zant from *Twilight Princess*
82. Agahnim from *A Link to the Past*
83. Vaati from *The Minish Cap*
84. Onox from *Oracle of Seasons*
85. One of the four giants from *Majora's Mask*
86. Koume from *Majora's Mask* (also appears as the boss of the Spirit Temple in *Ocarina of Time*)
87. The Moon from *Majora's Mask*
88. Kotake from *Majora's Mask* (also appears as the boss of the Spirit Temple in *Ocarina of Time*)
89. Chancellor Cole from *Spirit Tracks*
90. The five "Moon Child" characters from *Majora's Mask*
91. Ganon from *Ocarina of Time*
92. Fierce Deity Link from *Majora's Mask*
93. Hero's Spirit from *Twilight Princess*
94. Dark Link from *Ocarina of Time* (not 100%)
95. Link's mother
96. Link (again)
97. Golden Wolf from *Twilight Princess*

Comment: If you feel like putting in the effort, they're all named in this video; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UHnvFiniI_0

Comment: @Valorum That video is painful to watch which is why I didn't use it originally, but it's not quite so bad once I could skip through the video to the answers I still needed or wanted to confirm.

Comment: It contains all the answers, which is good enough for me

Comment: Sorry it took so long to get back to this. I made some edits according to my own knowledge. It looks good to me now.