# Can we identify all the characters in this Universe 113 poster?

Tags: character-identification, crossovers

I found this [Universe: 113 Character Poster](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/585926215/universe-113-character-poster), which features a whole bunch of sci-fi characters.

[image]

Who is everyone?

Comment: I don't see why this is being closed, we've had plenty of this, some of them with scores of people listed in the answer

Comment: @Edlothiad When I saw the poster I immediately thought to ask here precisely because I've seen several similar questions here before. For easier answering, perhaps a community wiki could be an idea.

Comment: Also needs a version with numbers or other labels to base the answer on.

Comment: The better question is, can you find Waldo?

Comment: Possibly the question could be expanded to include all the items listed on the kickstarter page: Over 140 characters, 40 Legendary items, 136 universes. Or someone could just email the artist for a list.

Comment: @JohnP With over 2k rep, you can edit the question yourself to include those three numbers :-)

Comment: @JohnP Good idea - looks like the top answer is including objects already!

Comment: I downvoted for "lack of research": the other similar questions gave the elements the OP already found by himself.

Comment: @Taladris Fair enough, can't argue with that

Comment: A higher resolution image (which certainly exists) would make this much easier.

Comment: @Gallifreyan He's the first one I randomly spotted. :)

Comment: @ArrowCase - Higher res version [here](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-Hxs3SY6mUxY/WdTjc45G6-I/AAAAAAADSKE/C7LRyNVCb-Yf5ZkZT25yhNhUjI_AuHUXACJoC/w1920-h2715/egor-klyuchnyk-small.jpg)

Comment: If you like this poster, see another one drawn by the same artist "Ultimate Space Battle" at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/195553/4918

Comment: I bought this one. My kids stole it.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

[image: same image with areas numbered]

*Numbering levels 11–0 from top to bottom, going through each level from left to right (unknown images are in **bold**).*

### Outside

- **unknown 'Motel' sign on the left side**
- Flag of the Democratic Order Of Planets (*Futurama*) in the middle
- Hatch to 'The Swan' facility (*Lost*) on the right side

### Level 11 (Top)

- [b] Vault hatch (*Fallout*)
- [b] Rick Deckard (*Blade Runner*)
- [c] [Soul Edge](https://soulcalibur.wikia.com/wiki/File:SoulEdge.png), a sword (*Soul Calibur*)
- [c] Philip J. Fry (*Futurama*) in cryotube
- [c] Kaonashi or 'No-Face' (*Spirited Away*) eating the Animal King Turret (*Portal 2*)
- [d] Cacodemon (*DOOM*) eating G-Man's briefcase (*Half-Life*)
- [f] Death Claw (*Fallout*)
- [f] Arthas the Lich King (*World of Warcraft: Wrath of the Lich King*)
- [f] Computer with two dots from 'A Rickle in Time' (*Rick and Morty*)

### Level 10

- [c] DeLorean (*Back to the Future*)
- [c] T1000 (standing) putting metal bar through T800's back (*Terminator*)
- [d] Kratos (*God of War*), falling
- [d] Bowser (*Super Mario Brothers*), falling
- [d] 'Born' resistance poster (*Half-Life 2*), grafitti next to Bowser's head
- [e]  Gandalf (*Lord of the Rings*)
- **[d-e] Unknown furnace, large red round body connected with tube to floor below and very thick black tube**
- [e] Jason Voorhees (*Friday the 13th*)
- [e] Headcrabs (*Half-Life*) coming out of headcrab shell
- [f] Shō Fukamachi (*Bio Booster Armor Guyver*)

### Level 9

[image: Level 9, E & F]

- [e] Poster with 'Earth' symbol (*Avatar: The Last Airbender*)
- [e] Kodama, a tree spirit (*Princess Mononoke*), on crate below *Avatar* poster
- [e] Orange portal (*Portal*), made by Krang
- [e] Kaneda's bike (*Akira*)
- [e] Krang (*TMNT*) holding a portal gun (*Portal*)
- [e]  [Sokolov's Elixir](https://img1.etsystatic.com/075/0/14557308/iusa_fullxfull.33455005_p53r.jpg) poster (*Dishonored*)
- [e]  [*Dwarf Fortress* poster](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebWMn.jpg)
- [e]  [*Pitman's Adventures* poster](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VbrYp.jpg)
- [f] Walker Gear (*Metal Gear Solid V*)
- [f] 'Lambda' graffiti (*Half-Life*)

### Level 8

- [b] Pinhead (*Hellraiser*)
- [b] Horny (*Dungeon Keeper 2*)
- [b] Briareos Hecatonchires (*Appleseed*)
- [b] V (*V for Vendetta*) or D (*Vampire Hunter D*)
- [b] Vash the Stampede (*Trigun*)
- [b] [Wurlitzer Jukebox](https://images.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fjukeboxesunlimited.com%2Fproducts%2FWurlitzer-1015-b%2FWurlitzer%25201015-b-1-W.jpg&f=1) (Possibly [BioShock](https://bioshock.wikia.com/wiki/Jukebox))
- [b] Iron Giant's head (*Iron Giant*)
- [b] Geralt of Rivia (*The Witcher* series)
- [b] Pyramid Head (*Silent Hill*)
- [b] Johnny Bravo (*Johnny Bravo*)
- [b] Worm aliens (*Men In Black*)
- [b] The Player as an @ symbol (*Nethack*)
- [c] Earthworm Jim (*Earthworm Jim*) in the little room below the bar
- [c] The Unkindled (*Dark Souls*)
- [c] Vectorman (*Vectorman*)
- [c] Poster of Amon (*Legend of Korra*)
- [d-e] Tachikoma, the spider tank (*Ghost in the Shell: Stand Alone Complex*), fighting Ed-209 (*Robocop*) with a 'Horde' duel flag (*World of Warcraft*) in the foreground
- [e] 'Fire' stone (*Fifth Element*) behind column
- **[f] Unknown hand reaching through the wall** ([Demogorgon from *Stranger Things](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J57s3.jpg)*?)

### Level 7

[image: Level 7 F]

- [a] Corvo Attano (*Dishonoured*)
- [b] [Transmutation circle (*Fullmetal Alchemist*)](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3718/what-are-the-transmutation-circles-in-fullmetal-alchemist-based-on-if-anything)
- [b] **Unknown tentacles**
- [c] 'Prawn' alien (*District 9*)
- [c] Porco Rosso (*Porco Rosso*)
- [c] CatDog (*CatDog*)
- [d] Poster with 'Wind' symbol (*Avatar: The Last Airbender*)
- [d] Robobrain (*Fallout*)
- [d] Sentinel (*Matrix*)
- [e] Anakin Skywalker's pod racer (*Star Wars, Ep. I*)
- [e] Alien (*Mars Attacks!*)
- [e] Crash Bandicoot (*Crash Bandicoot*) sitting in pod racer (*Star Wars, Ep. I*)
- [e] Big Boss (*Metal Gear Solid V: The Phantom Pain*)
- **[f] Unknown object leaning against TV** (looks like some sort of evil guitar?)
- [f] The Marker (*Dead Space*) on the coffee table
- [f] Squanchy (*Rick and Morty*) on the couch watching TV and holding something
- [f] Samuel Hayden (*Doom*)

### Level 6

[image: Level 6 C]

- [a] Idol (*Raiders of the Lost Ark*), buried outside
- [a] Tardis (*Dr. Who*)
- [a] USS *Enterprise* (*Star Trek*) as a toy or model, lying on its side
- [b] Pac-Man (*Pac-Man*), coming down the stairs and about to eat a cherry while chased by the ghosts Inky (*Pac-Man*), Sue (*Ms Pac-Man*), and Funky (*Pac-Mania*)
- [c] Courage the Cowardly Dog (*Courage the Cowardly Dog*)
- [c] Arzach (Mœbius's comics)
- [c] Nausicaä's glider (*Nausicaä of the Valley of the Wind*)
- [c] Robot (*Castle in the Sky*) crushed beneath rubble
- [d] The Iron Throne (*Game of Thrones*) with:

  - The Transistor, a large green sword (*Transistor*), lying across it
  - Kodama
- [e] Spider mutation (*The Thing*) next to table
- [e] Princess Mononoke's mask and knife (*Princess Mononoke*)
- [e] 'Water' stone (*Fifth Element*) under mask and knife

### Level 5

- [a] Skull of Bart Simpson or his twin Hugo (*The Simpsons*), outside
- [a] Finn and Jake (*Adventure Time*) hanging from wall
- **[a] Unknown skeleton**
- **[a] Unknown axe lying on ground**
- [a] Infernal Troglodyte (*Heroes of Might and Magic* series)
- [b] 'Earth' stone (*Fifth Element*) partly hidden behind floor 6 next to treasure pile
- **[b] unknown wand lying in treasure pile**
- [c] classroom with:

  - Spawn (*Spawn*) as the teacher
  - Stewie (*Family Guy*), first row
  - Zim (*Invader Zim*), first row
  - Pirana Plant (*Super Mario Brothers*), second row
  - Minion (*Despicable Me*), second row
  - Chappie, robot ([*Chappie*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1823672/))
  - Bart Simpson (*The Simpsons*), third row
  - Arnold (*Hey Arnold*), third row
- [d] Isaac Clarke (*Dead Space*) climbing down ladder
- **[d] unknown humanoid sitting** (Killy from *Blame*; Leon Kennedy from *Resident Evil*)
- [e] Jar-Jar Binks (*Star Wars*) being eaten by a Mimic (*Dungeons and Dragons*; Terry Pratchett's Luggage has square teeth and many feet...)
- [e] Eyebot (*Fallout*)
- [f] Kang and Kodos's UFO (*The Simpsons*)

### Level 4

- [a] Mob and Dimple (*Mob Psycho 100*)
- [a] X-16 'Miracle Machine' (*STALKER*), an enormous brain in a vat
- [a] Kodama, tree spirit (*Princess Mononoke*)
- [b] Alien eggs in the shadows (*Alien* series)
- [b] Genos (*One Punch Man*) doing dishes
- [b] Saitama, 'One-Punch Man' (*One Punch Man*), eating
- [c] 'Silent Hill' symbol (*Silent Hill*) on wall above the *Event Horizon* core
- [c] Koffing (*Pokemon*)
- [d] Sad Keanu Reeves meme
- [d] Tom and Jerry (*Tom and Jerry*, episode 'Blue Cat Blues')
- [d] Big Mouth Billy Bass
- [d] Saruman's Staff (*Lord of the Rings*)
- [e] The Lexx, an organic insectoid spaceship (*Lexx*), in miniature form
- [e] Chair used for hacking into the Matrix (*Matrix*)
- [e] Caleb (*Blood*) on monitor
- [e] Anomaly World Studio (image creators) logo on monitor
- [f] Totoro (*My Neighbor Totoro*)
- [f] Half-disassembled head of EVA Unit-01 or possibly [Evangelion Simulator](https://evangelion.wikia.com/wiki/File:Evangelion_Simulator_(Rebuild).png) (*Neon Genesis Evangelion*)
- [f] Kodama, tree spirit (*Princess Mononoke*)
- [f] Poster with 'Fire' symbol (*Avatar: The Last Airbender*)

### Level 3

- > [a] Waldo (*Where's Waldo?*)
- [a] X-16 'Miracle Machine' console (*STALKER*)
- [b] Excalibur (*Soul Eater*)
- [b] Poster with Water symbol (*Avatar: The Last Airbender*)
- [c] Executioner (*Alice: Madness Returns*)
- [c] Dickbutt (meme) on top bunk
- [d] Gravity Drive or Core (*Event Horizon*)
- [d] War (*Darksiders*)
- [d] Shark (*Jaws*), fin in water
- [d] Roger (*American Dad*)
- [d] Diablo (*Diablo*)
- [d] Rocko (*Rocko's Modern Life*)
- [d] Beavis & Butthead (*Beavis & Butthead*)
- [d] Groot (*Guardians of the Galaxy*) in a pot
- [d]  [Prof. Howard Pitman](https://www.artstation.com/artwork/APBeX) standing in doorway
- [d] Zerg hydralisk skull, from Raynor's ship (*Starcraft II*), mounted on the wall
- [e-f] A movie set with:

  - A Langolier (*The Langoliers*)
  - [e] Sandworm head (*Dune*)
  - [e] Batman, Superman, and Flash suits; Batman cowl, Silver-Age Flash helmet, and Superman wig (DC Comics)
  - [e] Bill the Triangle (*Gravity Falls*), directing
  - [e] Sonic (*Sonic the Hedgehog*), cameraman
  - [e] Stargate (*Stargate* and *Stargate SG-1*)
  - Ghost trap (*Ghostbusters*)
  - [f] Rubber suit filmed in a set of model skyscrapers (*Godzilla*)
  - [f] *Lord Grievous in the Mysterious Forest* (*Star Wars*), a separate image by the same artist, behind the *Godzilla* set

### Level 2

[image: Level 2 D]

- **[a] unknown skeleton**
- [a] [SCP-173](https://scp-wiki.wikidot.com/scp-173) with Class-D personnel containing a possible breach (*SCP*)
- [a] Slimer (*Ghostbusters*)
- [c] The Black Sphere (*Gantz*) by the escalator
- [c] [Pepelats](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0091341/mediaviewer/rm4276490240) (*[Kin-dza-dza](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kin-dza-dza!)*)
- [c] Jean-Baptiste Emanuel Zorg (*Fifth Element*)
- **[c] unknown lizard-man** (Kaiman from *Dorohedoro*?)
- [c] **Unknown man with shoulder spikes**
- [c] Facehugger (*Alien* series) in the circle
- [c] Headcrab (*Half-Life*)
- [d] Freddy Krueger's glove (*Nightmare on Elm Street*) in glass display
- [d] Lightsaber (*Star Wars*) in glass display
- [d] Noisy Cricket (*Men in Black*) in glass display
- [d] Dagger of Time (*Prince of Persia*) in glass display
- [d] Sauron's helmet (*Lord of the Rings*) on green counter
- [d] Vault-Tec computer (*Fallout*) on green counter
- [d] Crowbar (*Half-Life*) on green counter
- [d] Gravity gun (*Half-Life*) on brown counter
- [d] BFG9000 (*Doom*)
- [d] Doomsday device (*Futurama*) on the corner just above Predator
- [d] Pale Man (*Pan's Labyrinth*) behind the counter
- [d] Carl 'CJ' Johnson (*GTA: San Andreas*) in front of counter
- [f] Bender's head (*Futurama*), buried outside

### Level 1

- [a] Crocomire skull (*Super Metroid*) on bookcase
- [a] Cthulhu (H.P. Lovecraft's stories)
- [a] Hellboy (*Hellboy*)
- [a] Wampa-skin carpet (*Empire Strikes Back*) underneath Hellboy and Cthulhu
- [a] Lament Configuration (*Hellraiser*)
- [b] Alien (*Independence Day*)
- [c] [Frank Horrigan](https://images.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fimages-mediawiki-sites.thefullwiki.org%2F04%2F1%2F2%2F9%2F48223481451685564.gif&f=1) or other Enclave power armor user (*Fallout 2*)
- [d] Xenomorph (*Alien* series)
- [d] Guts (*Berzerk*)
- [e] Pearl, ['the fat vampire'](https://www.google.ca/search?q=Blade+%2B+fat+vampire&rlz=1C1NHXL_enCA691CA691&oq=Blade+%2B+fat+vampire&aqs=chrome..69i57.9007j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) (*Blade*)

### Level 0 (Bottom)

[image: Level 0 E]

- [a] 'Engineer Face' statue (*Prometheus*)
- [a] Swordfish II, a spaceship (*Cowboy Bebop*)
- [a] Eins, a dog (*Cowboy Bebop*)
- [b] Josef, a robot (*Machinarium*)
- [b] Harry Potter (*Harry Potter* series)
- [b] Vestal (*Darkest Dungeon*) beside Harry Potter
- [b] Fluffy, a three-headed dog (*Harry Potter*)
- [b] 'Wind' stone (*Fifth Element*) under Fluffy
- [d] Howl's Moving Castle (*Howl's Moving Castle*), the large wooden face
- [e] Predator (*Predator*)
- [e] A heptapod (*Arrival*), the star shape and tentacles above Predator, drawing a circular message in the air
- [e] Wayne Holden (*Lost Planet*)
- [f] GlaDOS (*Portal*)
- [f] R2-D2 (*Star Wars*)
- [f] Graffiti (*Half-Life 2*) on wall behind R2-D2
- [f] Containment unit (*Akira*)
- [f] Blue portal (*Portal*)
- **[f] unknown skeletons buried outside**

Comment: **Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66716/discussion-on-answer-by-sqb-can-we-identify-all-the-characters-in-this-poster).**

Answer (score 3):

**Level 8**

- Dungeon Keeper (at Bar)
- Geralt of Rivia? (at table with Pyramid Head)

**Level 7**

- Crash Bandicoot (in Pod Racer)
- CatDog (holding round card in ring)

**Level 5**

- Spawn (teaching)
- A minion
- Bart Simpson
- Arnold (Hey! Arnold)
- Stewie Griffin (Family Guy)

**Level 2**

- Jean-Baptiste Emanuel Zorg (Fifth Element) (Next to lizard at bottom of stairs)
- Facehugger (Alien)
- Pale Man? (Pans Labyrinth) (At counter with weapons)

Comment: How come you didn't just edit these into the original answer?

Comment: @Edlothiad He left a comment on the first answer saying he was having trouble getting edits in during the frenzy

Comment: Ah understood, this is a good way of doing it I guess!

Comment: Umm... if it is Dungeon Keeper related at the bar than it's possibly a "Horned Reaper" - however, it could ewll be the main bad guy from the film "Legend" ?

Answer (score 2):

At the very top of the mountain -- the flag of the Democratic Order Of Planets from Futurama.

Buried on the left side -- Bart Simpson's skull, the idol from Raider's of the Lost Ark.

One of the element stones from Fifth Element -- between the Luggage and the pod racer, laying on the floor.

Kaonashi is holding one of the turrets from Portal.

Answer (score 2):

**[c] unknown cylindrical machine or containment (behind the escalator)**
https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0091341/mediaviewer/rm4276490240

Pepelats — an interplanetary spacecraft (from the Georgian word "pepela" for butterfly)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kin-dza-dza!

Comment: Welcome to SFF:SE. We recommend having a look at the [tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour), which contains helpful hints for using the site.

Comment: I added that information into the community answer for you.  Good catch.

Answer (score 1):

I think 8[b] - "unknown humanoid with helmet sitting camera left of Horned Reaper" is Briareos Hecatonchires from *Appleseed*.

[image]

Comment: Why don't you just add it onto the answer that's already there with an edit?

Comment: The system won't let you if there is already an edit pending review for the post.

Answer (score 1):

"[e] unknown face on monitor" is probably Caleb from the Blood series of video games.
[image]

Comment: This looks like a plausible guess! :D

Comment: Oh absolutely, that must be it! Add it to the main post?

Comment: First time I stumbled upon this site is because someone linked to this page via Facebook, so I wasn't even aware how it functions, just wanted to contribute what I could.

Comment: @tobiasvl Your hat is too much for me!!

Answer (score 0):

**I**

I know giant-brain-in-a-vat screams Mother Brain (*Metroid*) but the console is absolutely lifted from the X-16 lab in *STALKER*; the brain vat itself also looks much more like the one from *STALKER* than any of the Mother Brains, which take up much more space and usually have spikes.

Side point: It's set in the Ukraine and we've got a Ukrainian artist here. The poster behind the *Godzilla* movie set is another piece of his.

**II**

The possible *Farscape* references don't seem to be accurate with higher-res versions of the picture.

**III**

Reddit thread going over the same image [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/gaming/comments/8ku1on/heres_a_wheres_waldo_i_think_youll_all_enjoy/). Given all their reposts, there are probably other similar threads lying around as well. Separate thread [here](https://e621.net/post/show/1363019) at e621 that someone at Reddit linked with warnings about NSFW ads. (I don't see them, but I use blockers.)

There's also a larger version of the image [here](https://www.artstation.com/artwork/4LOqW). Literally larger: they added a moon, sandworms, and several additional characters into the currently empty spaces.

Answer (score -1):

Level 10
[d] Unknown drawing next to Bowser (hand with an eye?)

Could be cover art from Star Control
[image: Starcon Box Art]
<sub>(source: [giantbomb.com](https://static.giantbomb.com/uploads/original/0/4/1121669-scan0001.jpg))</sub>

Level 7
[c] unknown humanoid boxing Prawn alien

Looks pig-like. Porco Rosso perhaps?
[image: Porco Rosso pigging out]

Answer (score -1):

The man sitting next to the ladder on the fifth level above the bottom floor is Killy from BLAME! 
You can determine it's him because of his very pale skin, his kinda bowl cut hair and especially his gun (the most famous item of the manga/anime) 
[image: Killy from BLAME!]